# Network-wide HTTPS: It's time

Tags: discussion, ssl, announcements

### Update 2017-05-22

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) is now `https://`. I've written up a lot of what it took to get here [in a blog post](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/).
Next up is chat and then `https`-only cookies. We'll be ramping up HSTS `max-age` directives as we go. I'll continue to update this post as we deploy new bits.

---

### Update 2017-03-16

We've redirected all child meta traffic from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`, and are now forcing HTTPS. We have also rebaked links inside the network (except comments) to point to the new domains and protocol. We'll get to comments at the end.

We are aware of [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) users getting too many redirects here, and unfortunately the issue is with their ruleset. I have submitted a PR to resolve this here: [EFForg/https-everywhere/#9110](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/pull/9110)

We are pausing further migrations while we observe how google handles sites like [Super User](https://superuser.com/) over the next week or so. I'll be back from vacation on March 27th and we plan to deploy `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` headers for reporting and proceed with full Q&A deployment across all main sites then.

---

### Initial post

This is a heads up, and a request for help. Related: original post [from our test site, Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time/345016#345016).

HTTPS for our entire network is [long overdue](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/), but we've been working hard on it behind the scenes. Expect a pretty big blog post when we turn it on everywhere that details the journey.

There are a few lingering questions on HTTPS we're not confident in until we do it live. One of these is the Google site move in webmasters. It *still* (to our disbelief) treats HTTP and HTTPS as different properties. I have no idea why. And the "change of address" tool [doesn't support such a move either](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en):

> **Note:** The tool does not currently support the following kinds of site moves: subdomain name changes, protocol changes (from HTTP to HTTPS), or path-only changes.

So we'll have to create [property sets](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/05/tie-your-sites-together-with-property.html) for *every single site* during the move to HTTPS. Fun!

Given the above, we need to see how all of this works in practice with real load:
**We're starting with [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)**.

Here's an order of things that's been going on (*per site*):

1. <kbd>done</kbd> Infrastructure in place:

   - A fast CDN/Proxy for local termination (Fastly)
   - Certificates (including IP pooling support to bridge HTTP/1.1 & HTTP/2)
   - Logging
2. <kbd>done</kbd> Get third-party support in place:

   - All per-site scripts onto our CDN and served securely
   - Ad providers to HTTPS
3. <kbd>done</kbd> Fix a ton of code that assumes `http://` in a million places.
4. <kbd>done</kbd> Prevent users from embedding new `http://` content (e.g. [forcing HTTPS images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343276/https-only-images)).
5. <kbd>done</kbd> Cleanup all existing user content that was `http://` (`https://` where possible, and converted to links if we can't embed it securely).
6. <kbd>done</kbd> Make sites render absolute URLs as `https://`.
7. <kbd>done</kbd> Move canonical URLs to `https://`.
8. <kbd>done</kbd> 301 Traffic to `https://` for all.
9. <kbd>done</kbd> **(Child metas)** Move from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`.
10. Force all Q&A traffic to `https://` (and set an https-only cookie)
11. Migrate all existing sessions to secure sessions (this will take time to run).
12. Use HSTS to ensure browsers don't hit Q&A sites via `http://` at all.

This is a really high level list, and there are a crazy number of nuances and edge cases to the above. This is for Q&A. Area 51, Chat, and [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) (the main site) have a separate set of concerns and code we'll address after Q&A. The list also isn't necessarily in order. While we're testing #6, [Samo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155005/m0sa) and I will be working on #11 at the same time.

But we have to do all of this across the network, and we're starting that process now. [`meta.stackoverflow.com`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) was our testing ground this week. While we're still waiting for Google's analytics to catch up so we can assess impact, we're ready to go on a few more sites. Here's our rough list:

1. <kbd>done</kbd> [`meta.stackoverflow.com`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)
2. <kbd>done</kbd> [`meta.stackexchange.com`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)
3. <kbd>done</kbd> [`security.stackexchange.com`](https://security.stackexchange.com/) (why? This community is well equipped to test HTTPS concerns and give feedback)
4. <kbd>done</kbd> [`meta.security.stackexchange.com`](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/) (moving to `security.meta.stackexchange.com`)
5. [`stackoverflow.com`](https://stackoverflow.com/)
6. <kbd>done</kbd> Q&A network **main** sites except stackoverflow.com (e.g. `*.stackexchange.com`, [`superuser.com`](https://superuser.com/))
7. <kbd>done</kbd> Stack Overflow localized child metas (e.g. [`meta.ja.stackoverflow.com`](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/) moving to `ja.meta.stackoverflow.com`)
8. <kbd>done</kbd> Q&A network **child meta sites** (e.g. `meta.*.stackexchange.com`)
9. <kbd>done</kbd> `stackexchange.com` (the top level non-Q&A domain)
10. <kbd>done</kbd> `area51.stackexchange.com`
11. (Planning required) `chat.stackoverflow.com`, `chat.stackexchange.com`, and `chat.meta.stackexchange.com`

We want your help simply reporting any issues with insecure content on `https://` or any other oddities you see. We'll try to address them as soon as possible. Since we get asked this a lot, yes - I'll write an exhaustive blog post about everything we hit along the way when we're finished here.

Comment: For 11. chat, how about you migrate chat.so to chat.se and have a problem less?

Comment: @Braiam That's not really a problem less, it's the same solution for all 3. However, it would create a ton of problems merging 3 databases, room lists, users, code assumptions, figuring out redirects for all time, etc. It's just not a win in any way :)

Comment: On the Google thing, they made this big deal about how it helps SEO and yet there's no indication it helps much, if at all. So the fact that WMT doesn't support it correctly doesn't surprise me either. Google wants HTTPS, but not badly enough to make it easier for people to make it work

Comment: Do you want bug reports as answers to this, separate questions tagged [tag:bug] and [tag:ssl], or something else?

Comment: There's a minor content security-related bug for [the editor preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291993/raw-link-titles-not-rendering-properly-in-preview) that may have been missed for #3. TO THE WHEEL OF BLAME!

Comment: But I would have to join a chat server less :(

Comment: What about ServerFault, AskUbuntu, MathOverflow (and potentially other custom-domain sites) in step 6 of the second list?

Comment: @SEJPM correct, they'll be about the same time.

Comment: The "share" permalink dialog on Stack Overflow still hands out http:// URLs (I'm logged in). Which will at least not be an issue once HSTS is rolled out.

Comment: @Christopher That's because we haven't switch Stack Overflow to HTTPS yet, that's step 5 in the bottom list :)

Comment: The Hot Meta Posts (on meta.SO itself) are not linked with https (not sure if caching, but it's been a while).

Comment: @Floern The links are `https://` *if linking to a site where it's enabled*, it's being enabled per-site as we re-bake content and transition things on the Google side. All links are rendered dynamically, in the context of the site they're going *to*.

Comment: How are you planning on moving the metas to site.meta.se? Will you have the Community bot go around editing them, or will that be on the users to edit their posts?

Comment: @NickCraver Ah, sorry, I thought that was maybe covered in the fixing of HTTP-related code. Fair enough! :)

Comment: This breaks Perl scripts that use the [core module File::Fetch](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-F.html) (using `http`)... [LWP](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html) works (`use LWP::Simple; my $content = get('https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen?tab=profile') or die 'Unable to get page';`), but this requires installation. [HTTP::Tiny may or may not be built in](http://perltricks.com/article/what-is-the-perl-core-/) and may or may not work for this (I haven't tried it).

Comment: @Riker We'll be doing a mass edit on our side to migrate sites - it'll have code and everything. Might even worth within the first 10 tries!

Comment: @NickCraver I'm getting sticky HTTPS from here on MSE to other sites.  E.g. I come here and it rewrites the URL to HTTPS, I use the supercollider to go elsewhere, URL *stays* HTTPS, and then when I go to that other site's meta I hit the cert error.  I gather that's not intended behavior?  I'm seeing it in Firefox 51.0.1 and reproduced in a private window.  I am *not* using the HTTPS Everywhere extension.

Comment: Followup: doesn't happen on Chrome 56.0.2924.87.  Maybe a Firefox bug?  (I'm not sure I want to use IE to break a tie...)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Are you using HTTPS Everywhere, or some other confused plugin? Our collider doesn't render `https://` links except to Meta.SO and Meta.SE right now (as intended). The URL generation is controller by per-site settings as part of the rollout.

Comment: @PeterMortensen What's "this"? Pretend I know nothing about your super secret always-encrypted programming language :) What's breaking? Does the lib not support HTTPS at all or something? Or...another issue?

Comment: I don't know if this is related to any of the https stuff, but MSE was giving me weird errors earlier when I was trying to follow some links there in Chrome while not logged in. Something like "you've had too many referrals to this site, please clear your cookies". (Sorry I can't give any more details - it's norepro while logged in, and I didn't take a screenshot earlier.)

Comment: @randal'thor There was indeed a 301 redirect issue (caching on the Fastly side), which we have addressed by changing how the Varnish cache key is calculated in VCL. Basically, it wasn't differentiating on `http://` vs `https://` in cache lookups on redirects by default...and that's crazy bad. They expect redirects to be done at the edge in VCL. This *will* be the case later, but not during the move while it's per-site.

Comment: @NickCraver no, I don't use HTTPS Everywhere.  Must be some weird Firefox thing, then.  (Reproduced in a slightly older Firefox version on a different machine.)  *Edit:* oh this is weird; it also happens to me on this machine in Chrome, but didn't on the machine I was using earlier. Maybe some userscript is to blame?  Will investigate; sorry to bother you.

Comment: Answer: it's SOUP.

Comment: @NickCraver - The (http) image in this question isn't loading in the iOS app - but is fine on web. From what you've written above, not sure anything is live on Sustainability SE yet - is this likely to be affected by some site-wide ssl changes, or is this a separate bug? http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/5883/why-does-cheese-have-such-a-high-carbon-footprint

Comment: What's the difference between https and no https?

Comment: @suomynonA Just search "What is https" on Google and you'll get some good results. Here's one: [What is HTTPS?](https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/https.html)

Comment: Not used to having my answers deleted - that much is troubling, is there that much orthodoxy around HTTPS everywhere that we (the programmers of the world) silence dissent?

Comment: @PeterTurner It was community deleted - I have undeleted it.

Comment: @PeterTurner  Nick's kind undeletion aside, I think it was correctly deleted, as it does not answer the question which is looking for specific technical issues with SE's HTTPS rollout.   It would be more appropriate as a separate meta question than as an answer here.

Comment: @David Wildcard certificates must be left-hand matches and single level, so `meta.*.stackexchange.com` isn't an option. I cover it with some examples in a blog post here: https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

Comment: thanks @NickCraver. I read your blog post (can't believe that it was 4 years old!) It looks like you all have chosen the best route forward, I just hope the meta domain switch does not cause major confusion.

Comment: You might want to add a Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only header so that users will automatically report mixed content and similar issues.  You could also add an `upgrade-insecure-requests` CSP header, though that's not ideal until you're done with everything else.

Comment: About the separation of identity and protocol in URIs: Facebook has the same issue, which makes migrating FB-indexed content to HTTPS hard or impossible to do without either data loss on the FB side, or manual intervention by an FB business account manager. I suspect that there is more web software out there that makes the same mistake, than does not. Is the solution really as simple as "PSA: Exclude the $protocol:// from URIs before using them as IDs"? I've noticed that there is a way to make a chat post turn into an out of band chat room on SE, but perhaps I do not have access to that yet...

Comment: Posted [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292236/278659) as a separate bug report since I'm not sure if it's related to the HTTPS stuff, but I suspect it is.

Comment: Have we officially reached  https on main sites? SU seems to be on HTTPS, but the page is not updated

Comment: @NickCraver Regarding the issue with Fastly and ignoring the protocol (https/ http), we have had to go through exactly the same issue with our site. Lots of pages ending up in infinite redirect loops which I had to accommodate through tweaking the VCL. It's a temporary thing as we will move to all HTTPS eventually but not just yet. It was a difficult one to track down.

Comment: Is there any plans to add CSP headers now that we are going full https?

Comment: @Braiam Yep, I'm working on it right now - I'd expect reporting to go out tomorrow.

Comment: @NickCraver I am curious if you folks were using a tool to scan for mixed content of pages - I have tried using https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/ and https://www.whynopadlock.com/ in the past but none of them are 100% helpful.

Comment: HSTS is a good idea. Lets wait for it. I wonder if we as a community can help...

Comment: **Network-wide HTTPS: It's too late**

Comment: The codegolf meta has been switched over to `https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com`, and it seems to be working fine, with one minor exception: my rep hasn't updated on codegolf meta for the last half hour :P

Comment: @ETHproductions we had an unrelated backend issue for a bit, rep should be syncing now.

Comment: Gravatar links on some pages are an issue -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292598/mixed-content-on-stackexchange-com -- if it hasn't been reported here yet.

Comment: *"(and set an https-only cookie)"* so is that http-only or secure-only or both?

Comment: Really? After the whine-fest that was had in this question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules) we're using KBD tags for formatting on a semi-official site wide notification?

Comment: Should this question be tagged status-completed?

Comment: @John It's not completed yet -- they still have to migrate SO, `stackexchange.com`, Area 51, and chat.  They also need to do #10-12 on the first list.

Comment: Any particular reason why Super User & Security SE were picked ahead of all other main sites?

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen Security.SE: "(why? This community is well equipped to test HTTPS concerns and give feedback)"; Super User is the most power user oriented site.

Comment: Will stackstatus.net (the status and postmortem announcer) also be updated to HTTPS?

Comment: @Nzall not at the time, Tumblr doesn't support encryption for custom domains - they're just not setup for it. I have no idea if they ever will. And you can't put them behind a proxy in general, e.g. CloudFlare, they're "not compatible"...which means they really don't like it, for whatever reason.

Comment: @NickCraver Understandable. SStatus doesn't really have any information worth encrypting either, so I don't think it would be worth it to put a lot of effort into encrypting it.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Why?

Comment: @NickCraver I posted a report, got linked as a dupe of this.  Shadow Wizard and rene seem to be suggesting that the system users (e.g. Feeds, id -2) have their avatars loaded in a different way from the others and end up HTTP?  They said to ping you on it.  Also, the "continue this discussion in chat" links are protocol-relative, and I was told to ping you on that, too

Comment: @Nick two words only: ***[WELL DONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaUsx.jpg)***. ;)

Comment: @Nick what about http://stackpromos.com?

Comment: Just curious: what's the purpose of changing `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: @DonaldDuck `*.meta.stackexchange` is a valid certificate, whereas `meta.*.stackexchange.com` is not. I covered the migration in a bit of detail here: https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/

Comment: Revision requested to: "I'll continue to update this post as we deploy new bits."

Comment: Some help articles seem to still have HTTP links, e.g.: the [roomba help article](/help/roomba) has an HTTP link at the bottom.

Answer (score 40):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Every time I visit https://meta.stackoverflow.com, it shows me that

**"This page is trying to load script from unauthenticated pages"**.

Is there something wrong here?

[image]

When I check what is happening in Chrome Developer Tools, this shows up:

[image]

**Mixed Content** : The page at `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full?cb=1` was loaded over **HTTPS**, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint `ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/`. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over **WSS**.

#### UPDATE

It also gives the same thing on https://meta.stackexchange.com:

[image]

Comment: FWIW, with HTTPS Everywhere on Firefox and loading that exact question URL, I get *Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at `wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/`.* in the Firebug console.

Comment: Apparently, **www.**meta.stackoverflow.com doesn't load for me, but removing the `www.` makes it load just fine

Comment: @MichaelKjörling FWIW means?

Comment: @SurajJain FWIW = For Whatever It's Worth.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an issue, since that site *never* existed. None of our domains are on `www.` (and we redirect from it if you try on the second level domains). Basically: this is nothing new, that domain isn't even in DNS.

Comment: @NickCraver what di you mean by none of domain are on www?

Comment: @NickCraver Actually as you can see in image , it give the issue when visited on non www.

Comment: @SurajJain I mean we don't use `www.` prefixes, we *sometimes* redirect from them to be handy, but that's it. I'm not sure why your secure websockets (`wss://`) are blocked or breaking (separate issue), but I've disabled insecure websockets (`ws://`) for the network in prep for the global move. Are you seeing the issue anymore?

Comment: @NickCraver What was really happening ? I am not seeing it anymore , What did you do ?

Comment: @NickCraver If you see in the image it was insecure socket ws not wss, that means on the site insecure socket was blocked secured are allowed

Comment: @NickCraver The page at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full?cb=1 was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.   You disabled the insecure websockets after my answer ??

Comment: @SurajJain insecure sockets are disabled across the network now, yes. Since they'd only result in mixed-content warnings everywhere soon. They were already only a fallback, but an invalid one going forward.

Comment: @NickCraver Just a question i did not understand what do you mean by they were only a fallback, but an invalid one going forward.

Comment: @SurajJain "only a fallback" means that ws:// would already only be used if wss:// cannot be used for some reason. Now that ws:// by design no longer works at all, if wss:// cannot be used, there is no point in even trying ws://.

Comment: @NickCraver Question, do you plan on utilizing HPKP to some extent or HSTS preloading?

Comment: @Avamander HSTS: yes, after the move. HPKP: maybe, there's a lot in play there (with subdomains) that's very tricky. More to think through there.

Comment: @NickCraver If i want to learn all about these terms and web what should i do.

Comment: @SurajJain Read https://scotthelme.co.uk/

Comment: @Braiam Thanks, CanI talk to you, I have few doubts?

Answer (score 23):

## The HTTPS Everywhere extension may cause trouble

…when HTTPS gets forced everywhere (step #10).

The reason is that the HTTPS Everywhere [ruleset](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/blob/master/src/chrome/content/rules/Stack-Exchange.xml) for Stack Exchange currently contains a **forced downgrade to HTTP** for all subdomains that are two levels deep, *such as `*.meta.stackexchange.com`*.

<sub>(You can try this now: install the [extension](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) and watch https://security.meta.stackexchange.com get downgraded to HTTP.)</sub>

Here is the offending rule:

> ```xml
> <!-- https links from other pages to these will cause MCB for important elements, hence the downgrades -->
> <rule from="^https://([\w.-]+)\.([\w-]+)\.stackexchange\.com/" 
>     to="http://$1.$2.stackexchange.com/" downgrade="1" />
> ```

Somebody probably needs to send a pull request with a fix (I might do this myself if I've got time for it) and it might be a good idea to wait until the fixed rule is in HTTPS Everywhere before you initiate step #10.

**Edit:** I dug trough the HTTPS Everywhere source a bit, and it does contain some logic to detect redirect loops; so, even with the downgrade rule in it, it should *eventually* give up and allow the HTTPS site to load.

Comment: Is this what is causing the `security.meta.stackexchange.com redirected you too many times.` error I get when I try to view the site in Chrome?

Comment: I have HTTPS Everywhere on Firefox and did notice this bug at first but now no longer and it properly serves me the HTTPS version.

Comment: I will be submitting PRs to the extension as we make network changes.

Comment: I've opened [a tracking issue](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/issues/9085).

Comment: A PR has been submitted here: https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/pull/9110

Comment: @NickCraver Glad to see you could get a fix in. I noticed a few oddities, though: 1. You're [excluding](https://eff.org/node/58830#exclusions) `meta.*.SE` [here](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/pull/9110/files#diff-c31c2f029e0be962512cc66e06cbe64bR50), wouldn't it make a lot more sense  to rewrite it to `https://$1.meta.stackexchange.com` instead? (Your pull request only rewrites `https://meta.*.SE`, not `http://meta.*.SE`) 2. You might want to add a `<securecookie>` for `*.meta.SE` 3. Might want to add a rewrite rule for `meta.*.SO` once those are ready. Anyway,  for your efforts

Comment: @user2428118 good points - to be honest I really only focused on fixing the immediate redirect issue. Since we'll be all HTTPS and using HSTS with secure cookies after the rollout, the end game is to just delete the vast majority of that ruleset. When we're *totally done* (chat, etc.), we should be able to delete it completely. Even things like elections.se.com are being moved to another domain (anyone have any suggestions?) for cookie security. The second level domain cookies should only hit our network at the end, all third-party services are being moving off. So much to do :(

Comment: @user2428118 To be clear: I *very much* welcome anyone cleaning up the rules further in the meantime (and I'll help them with as much information as possible), but I think *my* main efforts should be towards eliminating it. If someone is coordinating changes, ping me via `@NickCraver` on GitHub and I'll gladly answer any questions or review anything I can.

Comment: @NickCraver, your comment doesn't make clear whether you are aware of this: the policy of HTTPS-Everywhere is to delete rules only when the domain is preloaded. HSTS alone isn't enough.

Comment: @NickCraver  Pull Request is merged, It is completed. shall we mark it as status-completed.

Answer (score 21):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Area 51 thingies are breaking if you don't add the 's':

[Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Constructed languages http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/101265.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101265/constructed-languages?referrer=O-gl6OxAUH0bp1PVPExtMg2)

^with the autogenerated 'share this' link

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Constructed languages]

^manually changing the links from http:// to https://

To clarify: If you go the Area 51 proposal page, and click 'share this', and copy the embedded ad, post that somewhere on the SE network, the image will not show - it'll be a link, but not an image, as seen above. If you edit the links in the ad to have https:// instead of http://, the image shows up.

This appears to have been caused by 4.) on the list, because it's embedding an http:// link.

Comment: Which page are you referring to? Area 51 isn't enabled for HTTPS yet, as indicated in step 10 above :)

Comment: @Nick if you go to the Area 51 proposal page, and get the thing for the ad, it doesn't show the image, at least on SE. I'm pretty sure this is left over from the image switch. I'm going to see if it still works outside of SE...

Comment: So you're talking about visiting `https://area51.stackexchange.com`? If so, that's not supposed to work yet...see step 10 above. It's another codebase much more easily moved *after* the network (since we can assume HTTPS everywhere, at that point).

Comment: I don't know. I tried to post an Area 51 embedded ad link, as an answer and... it was broken until I edited the links to say https://.

Comment: @NickCraver I edited to clarify.

Comment: Ahhhh, I understand the issue now - sure I can fix that piece of Area 51 real quick - stand by.

Comment: If you do a hard reload of the Area51 page (to get new JavaScript), it should render an `https://` image to embed now. Cache breakers are also something I'll have to address in that ancient code later...

Comment: bolded the https and http, looks more readable now. is it ok ?

Comment: @NickCraver How about correcting links in posts by community user?

Answer (score 19):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

---

Title for question is not parsed from URL in posts body (at least in preview) if you use `https` on link or on site where you trying to post. E.g.

- open SO via `http://`

  > [image: https only not parser]
- open SO via `https://`

  > [image: all of not parser]

Link to post was acquired by `share` button for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42697372/3240681).

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291993/312043) ?

Comment: The share buttons will switch to `https://` as the site they're on does. For example, share links on this post are `https://`, while Stack Overflow isn't yet.

Comment: @NickCraver share link for current question is not parsed in preview.

Comment: @Arulkumar possibly a duplicate.

Comment: +1 for the freehand circles.

Comment: @alexolut Ah - I gotcha on the actual issue, noted for fixing, will try and do so first thing Monday.

Comment: Eh, it was bugging me. A fix is rolling to production now, thanks for the info!

Comment: @NickCraver the problem of HTTPS links not getting titles is still happening, though

Comment: @muru That should be fixed now - and the child/meta/parent relationships will be fixed in a deploy tomorrow (I'm just deep in a CSP header branch/refactor at the moment).

Answer (score 12):

Won't this breaks thousands of old JavaScript snippets that are referencing external scripts by http? Example: (note: I suspect no one is linking to jquery using http but it's at least shows the issue)

```js
$("#test").text("hello world");
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="test"><div>
```

[image: error message showing http references no longer work]

The majority of questions related to JavaScript libraries reference external scripts. Three.js, Pixi.js, etc...

[Here's a script that attempts to find snippets that have http references](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/v9sq1n7u/). It also lists mentions of jsfiddle, codepen, jsbin in case you want to move them to a snippet

Comment: For the moment, that only happens when hitting the "run code snippet" button (and not load)...we still have to figure out long-term on mixed content there.

Comment: You should use protocol-inferred urls: `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js`

Comment: @programmer5000 it's really better to use `https://`, which is HTTP/2 and faster in most cases there.

Comment: @NickCraver, what's the difference? I thought using `//` means "use the same protocol as the page. The browser will add `https:` to the request. So what's the important difference (not that I have anything against using `https://` instead of just `//` it's just AFAICT the result for SO will be the same.

Comment: @gman a) they're harder to deal with - there's a lot of code and assumptions that are harder, and b) in a `http://` context, they won't be delivered over HTTP/2, which is faster.

Comment: If you are on `https://example.com` and there's a content at `//example.com/*`, doesn't it use http/2 either way?

Comment: You also have the potential issue of the site being linked to not supporting SSL at all. Rewriting all HTTP URLs to HTTPS would break all HTTP links that do not support HTTPS.

Comment: I would extend it to all links to sites like http://lorempixel.com, often used for HTML and CSS snippets. But being able to do gUM in snippets for chrome is a good thing ;-)

Comment: @nick This was just a suggestion for sites that are being built with `http` for now but will move to `https`, to ensure a smooth transition. For many sites (such as my own, `https://programmer500.com`) `https` was a long term goal but not achievable immediately. I **definitely** support http**s**.

Comment: @programmer5000 We had relative links...they actually made the transition much more painful due to: what's relative? what's not? what's http? what's not? what has a valid cert? what doesn't? JS complications in checks, the same paths being unusuable in other contexts (e.g. emails and mobile apps). There are many downsides - I wouldn't advise that intermediate step for anyone else after doing it ourselves :) For a simple website (e.g. *only* a website), it *can* be a net positive, but with other pieces, it gets pretty complicated fast.

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the Android app, I have Mi Yodeya Meta pinned in my list of sites, and since the switch from `meta.judaism.stackexchange.com` to `judaism.meta.stackexchange.com` it has changed to saying `Unknown Site meta.judaism` instead of saying `Mi Yodeya Meta` and when I click it the app crashes.

Comment: Working on pushing a fix so people don't have to do this manually, but for now you'll need to log out completely in the app and log back in (it requests the list of all sites from the Stack Exchange API on login).

Comment: Manually removing and re-adding it will also fix the issue.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - Any update on the auto fix? Just got a new report on Arqade: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12333/28182

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

---

Receiving the `https://` error in the [Help center - Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/) pages, those contains the images in it. Still the images are as `http://` only.

The error is:

> [image: Https error]

In plain text:

> Parts of this page are not secure (such as images).

For an example, [Create Wiki Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) page contains an image as `https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXihi.gif`, receiving the warning due to this.

Comment: Noted - I've fixed this one but we'll have to address the help center globally - thanks!

Comment: @NickCraver "fix help center globally" there's a similar problem here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits - should we hold off on making issues with the help center for now?

Comment: @vcsjones Hmm privs need some more love. I just did all content/localized posts across the network, but privileges will need another code backfill for re-publishing. Noting down for Monday, thanks!

Comment: @vcsjones These should be resolve now - are you seeing any more?

Comment: @NickCraver did some clicking around and looks good so far.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The edits by Community to change from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com` are sending all the closed posts that have meta links to the reopen queue because they've been edited. This seems silly since the post wasn't really improved at all.

Comment: this is fixed now, edits on posts by community are excluded from queue the criteria

Comment: What about anonymous suggested edits?

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Once a number of comments are posted under a question or answer, the option will be offered to convert the comment thread into a chatroom:

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

Once a user confirms that, a new comment appears:

> Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64052/discussion-on-answer-by-edlothiad-is-arya-the-real-arya-or-is-arya-being-impers).

This link is still HTTP (though you'll be redirected to HTTPS automatically, *unless the room has been deleted in the meantime*, in which case you get a strange 'Object moved' 404 error page). Oh, and if you get to fix this, it's only a minor effort to implement [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247152/change-auto-generated-link-in-moderator-message-comments-moved-to-chat).

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Seems that protocol-inferred urls i.e. that begin with `//` have not been changed by Community ♦ user via auto-fix.

E.g. [in the post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4379/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E/4382#4382) on ruSO.meta link:

```
//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/305/
```

should have been changed to:

```
//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305/
```

But it wasn't. Using links from [revision 4](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/4382/4) leads to opening page with unsecure connection warning message.

Urls with explicit protocol using were succesfully changed, you could see it e.g. [here](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4613/revisions).

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

On most stackexchange.com domains, you are automatically being redirected from HTTP to HTTPS. E.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com leads to https://meta.stackexchange.com.

There are at least three subdomains for which this isn't the case:

- <s>http://area51.stackexchange.com</s> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as of 2019-01-09
- <s>http://api.stackexchange.com</s> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as of at least 2022
- <s>http://data.stackexchange.com</s> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as of approx. 2018-10-01

Are there any plans to change this, or is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Comment: Strangely Area 51 discuss [`http://area51.meta.stackexchange.com`](http://area51.meta.stackexchange.com) is automatically redirect to [`https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com`](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com), but not the Area 51 main site.

Comment: @Arulkumar That's because A51 Meta uses the `*.meta.stackexchange.com` wildcard rule, so it's automatically redirected.

Comment: @RandomPerson thanks, looks like they've fixed it regardless of Nick Craver's comment (now deleted). In the future, feel free to edit it yourself (the [status-declined] was added by a Meta regular, apparently based on Nick's comment, which is OK in my book).

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

From [Example newsletter popup is empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292201/307988)...

The example newsletter from the "Love this site?" ad is loaded (and blocked) in an iframe over HTTP, so all you see is a blank white lightbox/popup/dialog/whatever-you-want-to-call-it:

> [image]

Seems [the newsletter page itself does support HTTPS](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=meta.stackexchange.com) so changing the link to HTTPS fixes it:

> [image]

Comment: Got it, will fix Monday - thanks!

Comment: This will be fixed as cache expires over the next hour.

Comment: @NickCraver still not working for me.

Comment: @Nick still broken in the Edit Profile preferences section: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2UmC.png can you please fix it there as well?

Comment: @ShadowWizard 2 months gone and problem still exists despite of status-completed

Comment: @alexolut not really, the problem described in this answer is fixed (hence the status-completed tag is correct), what you found is a different problem, as it happens in a different place. Since Nick ignore our comments here, you can post a new bug report about it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard different problem with same behavior?

Comment: @alexolut exactly. Normally such two bug reports would be closed as duplicate, but we're dealing with only an answer here, with "non standard" way of marking it as completed.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

---

In the [Area51 proposal page for Qubes](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98519?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top), after I commited,

> [image]

Comment: Yep - we haven't done this yet - it'll come later in the list #10

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

When uploading an image in chat (SE), the link posted to chat is http instead of httpS.

[image: the upload dialog from chat]
[image: the resulting link uses http instead of https]

Tested on Opera and Firefox in private/incognito sessions, connecting to chat both through http and https.

Shouldn't be a difficult fix.

Comment: It's also worth noticing that the community bot did not convert Stack Imgur's HTTP images to HTTPS (while they can be converted just by adding the "s").

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools)

The [total page views](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/analytics?from=20170101&to=20170401&report1=pageviews) from the moderators dashboard in Meta does not show any data before Mar 16 2017, the day the switch to *.meta.stackexchange.com was done.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding SSL and Web server Security I have some knowledge, but instead writing paragraphs upon paragraphs of information about this, I will refer all who this may concer to the following link:

- [scan meta.stackexchange.com - Observatory by Mozilla](https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze.html?host=meta.stackexchange.com)

This website uses other websites such as - but not limited to - [SSL LABS](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), and [HTbridge](https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/)

Currently the score of meta.stackexchange.com is an "F":

[image: observatory.mozilla.org]

Comment: Yeah to be honest I'm not worried about this, at all. You're testing the very first phase of a many part move, the fact that all the pieces aren't in place is expected. The first phase is getting onto HTTPS for all traffic, which is better scored here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=meta.stackexchange.com&s=151.101.129.69&hideResults=on As an example, if I turned on `Secure` only cookies instantly without a migration, I'd log out millions of users. I happen to think that's a bad idea :)

Comment: OTOH SSL Labs [reports A](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: [status-deferred] then?

Comment: I get D- for meta.stackexcange.com, and F for StackOverflow??

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): moved to https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com

### Cannot access the Area51 Discussion Zone via HTTPS

Trying to access https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/ gives an error.

Screenie:
[image: Error!]

Comment: A51 codebase has trouble updating with rest of SE, news at 11.

Comment: `area51.stackexchange.com` is still in the todo list.

Comment: This isn't done yet - it's in the list above as not done yet...

Comment: There's a lot of code to move for this one - but it'll be moved to `area51.meta.stackexchange.com` as soon as time allows.

Comment: @NickCraver Uhm, I just stumbled across another issue regarding area51 and SSL... Try [this](https://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/19476/kronos) link

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Shorthand links in comments, like `[su]`, still resolve to `http://`, not `https://`.

Comment: Like this one: `[su]` = [su]

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
>
> Have just updated thousands of posts on SO, MSO, and MSE, changing `http://` to `https://` for all chat domains, the blog, data and stackexchange.com

As continuance of the question I wrote earlier today ([HTTP -> HTTPS script didn't change everything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332200/http-https-script-didnt-change-everything)):

Can we make the community user run a script to convert all links to chat to make use of the HTTPS protocol as well?

On MSE there are [681 occurrences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchat.stackoverflow.com) of the HTTP version of the link to chat.  <sub>[credit to Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332200/http-https-script-didnt-change-everything?noredirect=1#comment1083881_332200)</sub>

MSO has 459 occurrences and SO has 735 of them.

These are too many instances to handle manually, and also it would disrupt the front-pages disproportionately when done manually.

**EDIT:**
It appears there are [other links that haven't been converted either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332200/http-https-script-didnt-change-everything/332213?noredirect=1#comment1083935_332213), as pointed out by [Stormblessed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/399694/stormblessed). These are `data.SE` and `http://stackexchange.com`, with the latter having 1416 occurrences on MSE.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the Moderators tab in the Users page in a graduated site, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators, there is an "elected [year]" link below each user. This link is still in HTTP.

Comment: Is it a problem? There are default redirects to https. It only causes an extra 302 repsonse that could have been prevented. Unless I miss something

Comment: This post is over 2 years old now and no one is really paying attention to it. New bugs are better served by creatinga new question.

Comment: @animuson Well, it's a too small problem. Maybe not worth it.

Comment: @animuson Here you go: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376439

Answer (score 5):

I am currently getting certificate warnings on [When reviewing a suggested edit, how do I tell what question or answer it relates to?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227) from Chrome, but weirdly am not getting them visiting https://meta.security.stackexchange.com directly:

[image]

Comment: You loaded up before it was ready :) See the list in the post - we're not to child metas yet. **However**, we're starting that today, and https://security.meta.stackexchange.com is first up.

Comment: Can you still reproduce this bug?

Comment: @SEJPM No it seems to be working now. The little "not secure" is gone on the security meta too now.

Answer (score 5):

The [ssl](/questions/tagged/ssl) excerpt and wiki needs to be updated once TLS *is* supported (and the tag should probably be renamed from [ssl](/questions/tagged/ssl) to [tls](/questions/tagged/tls), but that's a different discussion).

Comment: [This was already discussed on Meta Crypto SE](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/a/549/23623) and we concluded it's not worth it.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Just an observation:

In the [Stack Exchange Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), some of the privilege page contains the other Stack Exchange post's link in it. Those links are still as `http://`, but when clicking on the links it will open as `https://`.

It is not cause any issue, but updating those `http://` links also will be uniformity with the links.

**Sample privilege page:**

In the bottom of the [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) page, there is the `http://` link

> Also see *[What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/)*

Comment: We'll be re-baking all links in the network to be `https://` everywhere (to eliminate 301s for users). We'll do this after the move of all of Q&A, since we can just assume `https://` across the board, do a rebake once, and simplify all logic involved.

Comment: Why did you roll back the automatic edit? Why have useless redirect?

Comment: @ShadowWizard See my comments in the [**Revision 4**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/292379/4): _In the actual privilege page the https url is not yet updated, so I changed back the http url in the post_. The issue is not yet solved.

Comment: I see. Well, still not sure we should actually quote the link as-is. It's clear enough what you request.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard This is now [tag:status-completed] right?

Comment: @RandomPerson yes, Nick did it years ago, and probably forgot about this specific post. :)

Answer (score 5):

## Main Tags on Meta Sites revert to “http”

If you type something like `[tag:foo]` or `[meta-tag:bar]` into a post,
you get something that looks like [this](/questions/tagged/this)
and links to
`site.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo` or
`site.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bar`<sup>1</sup>,
as appropriate. 
Based on a sampling of about ten communities,
if you go to the main (non-meta) site, using https,
and use the tag<sup>2</sup> Markdown,
you will get a link to the appropriate
https `questions/tagged/tag` URL. 
As expected.

In the communities that I tested, if you go to the meta site, using https,
and use the meta-tag Markdown,
you will get a link to the appropriate
`https://site.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/questions/tagged/tag` URL. 
As expected.

In many of the communities that I tested, if you go to the meta site,
using https, and use the **tag** Markdown, you will get a link to
`http://site.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag`. 
This is wrong.

These communities get it right:

- Meta Stack Exchange
- (Meta) Super User
- (Meta) Information Security

All other communities that I tested — including Stack Overflow — got it wrong.
___________
<sup>1</sup> or `meta.sitename.com/questions/tagged/bar`,
for those communities
(Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu, etc.)
not conforming to the `site.stackexchange.com` template.
<sup>2</sup> non-meta sites don’t recognize
the `[meta-tag:tag]` Markdown.

Comment: Surely that's correct for now? the communities that get it right are the only ones finished switching to HTTPS AFAIK...

Comment: @Cai: Well, I don’t know the full plan exactly, but (1) I got the impression that Meta Stack Exchange, ***Stack Overflow*** and Information Security were supposed to be done ahead of everything else, and (2) They’ve [been working](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/226030/195817#226032) for [over five years](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782/195817) to make the whole site https-friendly.  Having an https page explicitly generate a link to an http page (within the site) seems like [something they would have wanted to fix long ago](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/223728/195817).

Comment: no, not Stack Overflow... the only main sites that are currently https enabled are Super User and Security SE

Answer (score 5):

*Share* links from sites accessed via HTTP still give HTTP links (sort of, actually it's inconsistent: MSE always seems to give HTTPS, SO always seems to give HTTP), which makes sense, except you might want to consider forcing them to give HTTPS links instead because:

- There's a ton of HTTP links that exist into the sites still (for example, Google links mostly go to HTTP, old browser bookmarks and autocompleted URLs, etc.), meaning lots of people getting non-`https` share links.
- This will help reduce the load of HTTP → HTTPS conversions in posts.

There is some [pretty compelling evidence for this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/643613). On SO, for example, since March 10 (the date of this announcement), and as of about 8 hours ago (good timing on the SEDE update):

- 7,938 posts have been created that have a link to stackoverflow.com in some form.
- 7,616 of those use HTTP and not HTTPS.

That's a whopping 96% of new SO-link-containing posts that end up having HTTP links in them.

To be clear, that's not to say that all of those are a result of share links. Those numbers are evidence that a lot of people are visiting via HTTP (because the links they post will either be share links or copy + pasted from their browser bar). But to me, it follows that share links should probably be converted.

SO was used as an example, I presume the pattern is similar elsewhere.

[There is an old feature request about this here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238192/make-share-links-https) that should probably be revisited.

To that end you probably also want to start serving redirects at some point from the HTTP pages to HTTPS. That'll take care of the "copy link from address bar" end of things, plus all the external HTTP links that you have no control over.

Comment: On sites that are HTTPS default, the share links are HTTPS. It's not dependent upon you you accessed the page, they (intentionally) match the canonical. They'll shift over as the site does.

Comment: @NickCraver Ah I see, so SO isn't shifted over yet (which aligns with lack of `done` next to item 5 in your second todo list)? That's why [the links are still HTTP there](https://i.snag.gy/s3GIfH.jpg), right? I can see that MSE and MSO all have HTTPS share links, which also lines up with the progress lists you've posted.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[As noted here on Area 51 Meta](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13597/area-51-openid-login-is-broken-with-https/27726#27726), OpenID login on Area 51  still goes through an insecure HTTP request (and breaks if that request is rewritten to use HTTPS, e.g. by HTTPS Everywhere).

[I've reported the latter issue to the HTTPS Everywhere devs](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/issues/14452), and they've added an exclusion for the problematic URL for now.  But that does nothing to fix the real underlying issue with the insecure login URL.

(Ps. I'm about 90% sure that the only thing needed to fix this is adding the missing `s` to the OpenID return URL parameter in the Area 51 codebase.  Letting HTTPS Everywhere rewrite the URL to use HTTPS does work, in the sense of apparently reaching the correct OpenID authentication endpoint, but the auth code then detects the rewrite as an unexpected URL modification and aborts the login process.)

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

---

Receiving the `https://` error in the [Area51 proposal page for Qubes](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98519?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top), those contain a script in it. Still the script cause an error, despite it being over https: https://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js

In plain text the error says:

> Parts of this page are not secure (such as images).

Comment: [It's not the Quantcast script that causes the error, but various Gravatar user images that are loaded over HTTP.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvdGV.png) This also happens with my own Gravatar icon in the top bar.

Comment: @user2428118 Strange, I've used Firefox' *Developer > Network* tool and it shows that particular script. (Note: I was also having the HTTPS Everywhere extension on)

Comment: @NickCraver https://stackexchange.com/ is still serving Gravatar images over HTTP.

Answer (score 4):

Will api.stackexchange.com continue to be available though HTTP?

Comment: The plan is to force all traffic over to `https://` - but I am of course curious why you're asking...

Comment: Actually mostly because of things like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111735/leaderboard-golf/112195). With forced HTTPS it may be trickier to use SE API without proper frameworks and libraries. One can type HTTP request in netcat, but not HTTPS request.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> We have also rebaked links inside the network (except comments) to point to the new domains and protocol.

I still see `http://` links in Super User posts.

E.g. in my question, [Advertisement suddenly appearing on top of almost every page](https://superuser.com/q/831994/213663#832009), the original `http://` links (e.g. the `http://superuser.com/q/831994/213663#832990`) are still `http://`.

Unless I misinterpret the above statement.

Comment: superuser links were processed just now, including [your example](https://superuser.com/posts/831994/revisions)

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Apparent [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[HTTPS conversion seems to have cancelled newsletter subscriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292476/162102)

So far this only affects MSE, but before rolling out changes to the rest of the network, I suggest investigating to either fix it or announce that people will need to re-subscribe to their newsletters.  (Either's fine IMO; it's the silent drop we want to avoid.)

Comment: I'm digging into this now, hope to get all the data fixed up today.

Answer (score 4):

With the deployment of https I see a huge drop in StackOverflow referral traffic in the analytics of our own site. Many of the links in SO that point to our site were written when we had no https equivalents (we've moved to https a while ago, though). Since by default referral information is not passed from https to http sites, the information now gets lost and I see a decrease by a factor of about 20 in the referrals. That's not really a big problem, because people are *probably* still clicking on the links and are being successfully directed to our site, however they do not appear in analytics anymore and StackOverflow suddenly dropped dramatically in the referral ranking, which is sad from the analytics point of view.

Would it be possible to employ the ["unsafe-url-referrer-policy"](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/#referrer-policy-unsafe-url) on SO sites? That would reenable referrers for links that are still targetting http sites.

Comment: Think it's worth of a new feature request.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools)

The [total page views](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/admin/analytics?from=20170101&to=20170401&report1=pageviews) from the moderators dashboard in Meta Stack Overflow in Spanish (*Stack Overflow en español*) does not show any data at all.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) [per-site-meta](/questions/tagged/per-site-meta)

Links to comments (I didn't check for another stuff) in Stack Exchange Data Explorer should be fixed for persite metas. E.g. from `meta.ru` to `ru.meta`:

> [image: meta.ru]

Tested in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/rume/query/712472/top-100-most-upvoted-comments) for ruSO.meta.

Comment: Proper bug report [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296629/sede-magic-columns-and-site-do-not-use-https)

Comment: @rene looks like that bug is fixed. In my case there is `https` already.

Comment: On second thoughts this is better raised as a specific bug for [tag:sede]

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

---

I was trying to add a comment to [Worldbuilding's writing a blog post about TRAPPIST-1. What should we include in it?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405/worldbuildings-writing-a-blog-post-about-trappist-1-what-should-we-include-in) (asking whether it’s time to un-feature it, so not too important). However, the red notification “An error occurred while adding this comment” appears instead, and the browser console shows these mixed contents warnings (in German):

[image: screenshot of browser warnings]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the errors handy? Thanks!

Comment: @Adam Lear: Added, but it’s in German. :) The problematic thing for posting the comment is the second line from the bottom, the URL ending in `/comments`.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

All of the child meta sites are giving me a redirect loop in Chrome when I navigate to them from the top menu. I have already deleted all my browsing history (and had to login again after that) without any result. It works fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer 11, but Chrome (which I use for 95% of my browsing) gives a redirect loop error.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS Everywhere? If so, this is caused by one of their rules and I've submitted a PR to fix it here: https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/pull/9110

Comment: @NickCraver Actually, yes I am. Weirdly enough, I did read the other answer when checking if noone else had the issue, but I didn't make the connection and thought it was due to some cached redirect rule on my end.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Profile page pictures don't show up when using the https:// versions of the site.</s> Nevermind, this seems to be that Gravatar had lost the PG version of my profile pic - it has the G version and others, but SE is trying to load the `&r=PG` version. I've fixed that

---

Additionally the hyperlink when clicking on the picture (or rather where the picture should be) redirects to the http:// site.

[Example:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42295/tom-carpenter?tab=profile)

[image: Non-HTTPS Picture]

On the profile page as well, I've the SE flair in my profile. Other people also have images in their profiles. Currently this is still using the `http://` link. I have updated that now manually, but I was wondering is it worth all pictures in profiles being automatically updated to `https://` links where available?

Comment: we don't default codegolf to https yet

Comment: @m0sa the profile is network wide, so the last paragraph still applies to SO and SU. When I went in to change the profile it did say only HTTPS images allowed, but I assume it would make sense that those are changed over automatically just like Q&A. On sites like EE.SE/Codegolf/whatever, if you navigate to the HTTPS site, all links on the profile page except for the profile image one are staying on the HTTPS version of the site. That's why I assumed it was a glitch.

Comment: @TomCarpenter The *link* is `http://` because the site doesn't default `https://` yet. The **picture** is `https://`...that's a separate Gravatar issue. We're discussing how to move off of them internally now, as they don't seem to care all of their stuff is breaking left and right anymore. As an example, your [Super User profile](https://superuser.com/users/180661/tom-carpenter?tab=profile) *does* link to `https://`, because it has switched over.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

- [Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: Message signature was incorrect on Area51 only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274619/316281)

It is [suggested by @Adam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291957/316281) that this can be fixed when full HTTPS support is rolled out network-wide.

Comment: I don't think it is proper to re-post a bug report here as answer. Having it either as answer here or a separate report is enough.

Answer (score 1):

When I visit `meta.math.stackexchange.com` I get:

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
meta.math.stackexchange.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit 
cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

Comment: Where did you get a link to that? The site is https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ - the old meta address *never* worked under HTTPS (and likely never will).

Comment: @NickCraver I just added meta to the beginning

Comment: @NickCraver But, now it's working fine, it just redirects.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Old chat links to Meta posts, like the oneboxes from feeds, have been migrated from HTTP to HTTPS, but the domain change isn't processed.

An example is [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=32601092#32601092). The [history](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/32601092/history) shows the original link was

```
http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/please-dont-vote-to-close-spam-questions
```

but it's now

```
https://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/please-dont-vote-to-close-spam-questions
```

which gives an SSL error. It should be

```
https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/please-dont-vote-to-close-spam-questions
```

instead.

Comment: Already reported: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297042/chat-links-to-meta-sites-have-been-rewritten-with-invalid-https.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [chat](/questions/tagged/chat)

When linking to insecure third party images, the embedding in chat causes mixed content warnings. I guess a fix involves rehosting images on i.stack.imgur.com (if feasible) and stopping the embedding of all other insecure content.

Answer (score 1):

**Links from Help Center to Meta Stack Exchange**

It seems that many links from Help Center to Meta Stack Exchange are http rather than https.

I've noticed this when looking at [Help Center > Privileges > Access To Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

`See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that`

The link given there is http rather than https and it is shown as url rather than as the post title. (The same link is expanded to the full title in a post to the full title, even if I post is with http: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

EDIT: Correction to the preceding paragraph - it is expanded in the preview, but it is no longer expanded after I post an answer. This seems to be another bug - but I guess this must have been noticed and reported before. With https it is expanded both in preview and in the actual post: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

After that I checked a few other entries in help center. As far as I can tell, all links *to Meta Stack Exchange* are http and not https. But I did not find example similar to the above. (In the entries I looked at, those links were displayed as some text rather than as a bare url.)

Comment: I hope this is the correct place to posted something like this. Originally I posted this as a separate question, but since is probably a better place, I have deleted that question.

Comment: I guess this is fixed...

Comment: Here is a separate post related to http-links in the help center: [Help has non-HTTPS links in it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327823)

Comment: Martin, this has been fixed, right?

Comment: @RandomPerson Basically, yes. From what I was [told by Yaakov Ellis](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1632/conversation/http-https-links-in-the-help-center), if some pages in the help-center have been customized for a particular site, those ones has to be fixed manually by the moderators.

Answer (score -61):

What I don't understand is why this site *needs* ssl.  Is it just to avoid getting hassled by web browsers?   I've been using stackoverflow for a long time, since the beta, has anyone been hacked?   The personal details page is not much of a life-history, and aside from careers, it doesn't store enough information about us to even make accessing that particularly useful.

I would much prefer a micro-revolt against this trend toward ubiquitous SSL, no mom-and-pop restaurant with a hundred-dollar-per-year home-built static website advertising their menu wants or needs to have an SSL tax foisted upon them and it should be up to us, the programmers of the world, who can see a tad clearer about these things than the corporate bigwigs, that should do whatever we can to avoid them and reclaim sanity.

Basically, it makes no sense to encrypt this text therefore it should not be encrypted.   It is a waste of processing power and bandwidth.

Based on the comments, and what I know about this technology (and I only have years of hands-on experience, you can tell I'm not an expert in any useful sense)  is that

1. You wanted http/2 features.
2. You can't get them without https.
3. The reason you can't get it without https is because the browsers are against it.

What I read from that is that browsers (cough *Chrome*) are against it because it is in their best interest to be the only thing between your eyeballs and the webpage.  People don't trust the ISPs (whose service they pay for), but they do trust Google, whose purpose is to sell you stuff...  Tell me again why we're falling for this?

Comment: You can get SSL certificates for free easily now (Let's Encrypt). Moderator accounts for example are much more critical as they have access to PII, but are vulnerable to certain kinds of attacks while SE doesn't use SSL. SSL also prevents certain kinds of obnoxious behaviours from middlemen like ISPs adding ads to pages.

Comment: @Mad that still doesn't address the environmental concerns.

Comment: I think you're overestimating the computational cost of SSL. For sites pushing large amounts of static data (e.g. netflix or youtube) it makes a small but noticeable difference. For stackoverflow rendering the page should be significantly more expensive than encrypting it.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that the environmental concern is valid?  Given that the additional processing load was down to negligible levels even when only considering HTTP processing 10 years ago, in the grander scheme, I strongly suspect it's too small to measure at all today.

Comment: If you want to start a flame war for SE for their 'support' for Donald Trump, I would consider [reading this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342440/993547). Your tone is against the Be Nice policy by the way.

Comment: HTTP 2 pretty much requires HTTPS support. We've seen that it makes a huge difference. It is also helps users who's ISPs inject content into the page - with HTTPS that can't happen. There are lots of good reasons to use it.

Comment: Better security, less bandwidth, faster response times (HTTP/2), better privacy, protection from injections. As for your initial post, there are a lot of bad assumptions there. Our site's energy footprint is *tiny*. In NY use about [16kVa](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/834160435066728451) of energy (Denver uses far less). That's about 130 100w light bulbs, or lighting for a small company. We take great pride in our efficiency and the remarks on energy impact are baseless. The impact on our numbers likely won't be even be big enough to measure.

Comment: @Nick it's not you, it's all the routers in between.   Some people say [https is faster than http](https://samrueby.com/2015/01/26/why-is-https-faster-than-http/), that's gotta be straw-man http though. I mean who runs either without compression?    If you apply the categorical imperative to the question of encryption and say, "is it good that everyone encrypts their website regardless of its purpose?", I think the answer is no.  There is no _purpose_ to encrypting 98% of stackexchange, therefore why encrypt all of it?

Comment: HTTP and HTTPS are layer 7 concerns, routers are dealing with layer 2 and 3. HTTPS is faster because every major browser decided that HTTP/2 features are almost exclusively enabled on secure connections. This isn't part of the spec, but how browsers do it and ultimately all that matters. With HTTP/2 we can push resources to the client faster for example, rather than waiting for another request to get the CSS, etc. That requires HTTPS. There are several purposes and you're willfully ignoring them, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @nick I used to get around that by using separate domains for images, css, etc,  you couldn't do that with https without getting a stern warning.   I'm not ignoring the purpose of https, I think it's great for banks and facebook, but pointless for _this_ website.    IMO it is bad that the major websites follow suit because the browsers go one way, the Internet should drive in the opposite direction.

Comment: @PeterTurner You don't get around this with multiple domains. You're likely talking about concurrency limits which is an entirely different thing. Push is a new HTTP/2 feature effectively gated by HTTPS. To be frank: none of what you are saying is true. And saying all websites should go opposite to what browsers are doing (both exist to serve users) is just absurd. Again, that makes no sense at all.

Comment: HTTPS is *far* more important than just avoiding "getting hassled by web browsers."  Ever heard of Firesheep?  If I'm sitting in a coffee shop and not using HTTPS, *anyone* could get access to my account.

Comment: @nobody you're first sentence is the opposite of what I'm talking about, https allows web browsers to corner the market on hassling us.    But you're right about the firesheep stuff.

Comment: @PeterTurner I'm not sure why you think web browsers are the enemy.  The reason they "hassle" us to use HTTPS is *because* of attacks like Firesheep.  Encryption is the only way to get privacy and security on the Internet, and the drawbacks of using HTTPS are next to zero as other commenters have explained.

Comment: Honestly, given the numerous exploits ISPs have deliberately perpetrated against their paying customers, and the exactly zero exploits deliberately launched by *any* browser maker I've heard of against their *free* users, I haven't the foggiest why anyone would trust ISPs to boil water without introducing a new backdoor.

Comment: @Nathan I can understand not trusting ATT and  some other cable companies who became ISP's, but the mom-and-pop ISPs scattered throughout the country aren't doing what you're accusing them of and the top links in google and bing are exactly tied to what you're searching for - these companies now have exclusive access to you.

Comment: @PeterTurner: I don't know what you're trying to say, exactly, as I don't use IE, Edge, or Chrome, and all browsers allow changing default search engines, and general browser usage is not where Google and Bing get their ad targeting, and tracking is a far cry from actual malware. (Also, my local mom-and-pop ISP hijacks DNS responses to inject parking pages.)

Comment: @joonas but noone with half a brain, not even the mom and pop EMR I used to work for, had http on a logon form. Its not cool to have your cookies snooped and one accoumt hacked, but it isnt the same. I dont mind the chastisement firefox is doing to logon forms with http.

Comment: @PeterTurner so you're advocating for HTTPS on the login form while insecure HTTP everywhere else? If you already had to do the work of securing the login page, it'd be pretty much the same effort to secure the entire site. And no, pointing to secure page from an insecure page (like frontpage) is not okay, since it exposes you to MITM.

Comment: @joonas it's not the effort to secure that I'm talking about, it's idea that insecure http is inherently bad for all websites - it's not.   That's like saying billboards on the highway should have decoder rings.

Comment: @PeterTurner it's inherently bad for performance, which I've covered and will provide aggregate data to back up in the blog post. Also also cookie access, proxy caching, etc. But you seem to want to just ignore all the arguments you don't agree with here, that's not a healthy or productive avenue of discussion in any situation.

Comment: @nick i am keeping an open mind. I am arguing that http serves a purpose of maintaining an open and free Internet based and eradicating it only serves the purposes of the application layer providers which is why they chose not to incorporate the unencrypted protocol.  If you can convince me that compressed encrypted data can traverse the Internet faster than compressed unencrypted data I will be sold on that point - there would be no reason for stackoverflow not to convert (I still don't approve of them deprecating my childhood)

Comment: @PeterTurner He's already said it does - HTTP/2 push is faster than without it, because it's one request not (say) 5.

Comment: @tim but that is http/2 not https.

Comment: @PeterTurner which browsers enable http/2 without https?

Comment: @tim that is the point I am trying to make

Comment: @PeterTurner you said to prove that https is faster. in the real world, the world we live in, https is faster because of http/2

Comment: @tim but if http were supported, it would be faster. Firefox is opensource as is chromium, you could probably hack together a browser that supports http/2 over http. But, since that hack would consist in _not_ calling public key encryption functions, it goes without saying that it'd be faster.  Still not the point though, the point is the browsers are colluding against the ISPs because they think they have the moral high-ground in the net neutrality debate. They are ending debate by anonymizing all content through encryption, giving them the upper hand in the only thing making money online.

Comment: @PeterTurner yes how terrible Chrome is forcing my browsing data to be private, and stopping 3rd parties exploiting http. how annoying !?

Comment: The negative of https is that it requires certs, certs require domains (+) both are controlled by 3rd parties which means the internet will be more gated (those 3rd parties get to control who gets a domain, who gets a cert, and both can be revoked). I can see taking a stand against https for that reason but unfortunately http is not a solution for that problem. (+) well, except for manually installed private certs). For SO though https seems a win on all levels.

Comment: @mad I looked in to letsencrypt.org last night. Looks like they only offer 90 day certs.  I'd imagine all the yahoo site builder gramdmas of the world are going to love sshing imto their websites 4 times a year to do that.

Comment: @PeterTurner Let's Encrypt is meant to be used with automatic renewal of certificates, that's why they're only valid for 90 days. Some hosters implement Let's Encrypt, so it's just a checkbox to click, though I haven't looked at those personally. If you do it by hand, every manual for Let's encrypt shows how to set up renewal for the certs, so you never do it by hand.

Comment: @MadScientist Correct, on my hosting server, I have it set up to automatically run through and reissue every Let's Encrypt cert every 88 days (from that cert's last renewal). It's clean, painless and costs nothing. The only thing I miss, that Let's Encrypt does not have, is wildcards. So it adds a bit more set up time.

Comment: -1 for "I need more downvotes".  *I got your back, man!*

Comment: @PeterTurner CloudFlare offer shared certs for 15 years.

Comment: Eventually SSL will become the defacto (if it isn't already) and will just be another step in setting up a website. Imagine having an internet in the early days without DNS. When DNS was invented and started getting used I'm sure everyone complained that now, gosh, they have to pay for and setup a DNS server/entry just so their website will work for the majority of consumers. Now it's just something you do when setting up a website. In the long term we can be thankful DNS exists. Rather than asking what the merits of encrypting the internet are, you should be asking what the disadvantages are.

Comment: @jduncan I was trying to point out the disadvantage.  For one thing web crawlers will need to read it.  Could duckduckgo have gotten off the ground today crawling an encrypted Internet?    Google and M$ have enough infrastructure to solidify their control over indexing the encrypted Internet.

Comment: I strongly fail to see the connection between "webcrawlers work" and "HTTPS is universally" used. Note that HTTPS _does not_ imply that all the content is hidden behind authentication from the client side, but rather is a change on the transport layer which should have _no impact whatsoever_ on one's ability to inspect websites for crawling purposes.

Comment: @sejpm isn't it gonna be a lot more work to index https://stackoverflow.com than http://stackoverflow.com?  The ability is there, the number of cycles required to do the work goes up.   It would be like going from reading War and Peace a million times a day to reading War and Peace in Turkish a million times a day.

Comment: A full TLS handshake should take [~6ms computation-wise](https://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html) (on a single core without the crazy optimizations libraries like OpenSSL do against a server with an RSA certificate and using DHE which is more expensive than ECDHE), plus the minimal overhead due to symmetric cryptography and state / verification logic. Overall I strongly suspect the client-side overhead of HTTPS to be in the single-digit percent area.

Comment: @PeterTurner Remember that the most widely used algorithm in TLS (AES) is hardware accelerated on almost every piece of consumer hardware sold in the last 3 years, even longer for servers. Even without hardware acceleration, the overhead TLS would add compared to the actual parsing and work done to index web pages would be so tiny, you'd be hard pressed to measure it. It seems your entire argument leans on the fact that you believe that TLS is some how a lot more computationally expensive than plain text, which, in today's day and age is simply not true.

Comment: @PeterTurner Straight from the horses mouth, Adam Langley (from Google) [posted back in _2010_](http://bit.ly/1ekcpsv) statistics on SSL overhead on his blog. To quote him directly _SSL/TLS accounts for less than 1% of the CPU load, less than 10KB of memory per connection and less than 2% of network overhead_. Offset that with the fact that HTTP2 speeds up connections by over 50% in most instances, you've actually gained performance overall. It all comes down to whether the benefits of SSL offset the "1%" loss in performance, and in this case the answer is overwhelmingly yes.

Comment: @jdun good, at least someone finally admitted any loss in performance (which is just common sense) everyone else here just glosses over the fact.   I can't wait to see http/2 actually speed up things, my guess most big sites will just pack more crap in and it'll be a wash.  I wonder if Google also needs http/2 in order to become a competitive ISP.  The commodity price on chunks of Internet bandwidth has gone down so drastically in the last few years - if they could shrink the actual footprint of the Internet bandwidth, they could decimate the companies who trade in that stuff.

Comment: @PeterTurner HTTP/2 doesn't necessarily decrease the amount of data sent, rather, it sends it more efficiently (eg. pipelining, HTTP/2 PUSH etc). The ISP's still have to carry the same amount of data, it just gets to the end user quicker.

Comment: @jdun so do web servers have to recognize when crawlers come by and not send them PUSH stuff or do crawlers (and curl) have a mechanism to not request it?  I guess I can go figure that out myself with curl once my wife gives me my computer back.

Comment: The reason some people consider browsers the enemy is that they're essentially forcing the issue to move to HTTPS, instead of letting it win out naturally. It seems underhanded to not work on HTTP2 to spec in order to make it where HTTPS is faster. It's as if the browsers, not the websites themselves, are making the decision. It's like when everyone was upset at the NYC large soda ban. It may be better for them, but they don't want to be forced to do it.

Comment: @PeterTurner In order to get a HTTP/2 connection, a client has to announce that it has support for it via [ALPN](http://bit.ly/2mHBZ1u). Once a client announces it has support for HTTP/2, then it can request that the "push stuff" be disabled (it may not support it, or want it). If the client does not support HTTP/2, it just connects like usual and accesses the site via HTTP/1.1 over a standard TLS connection.

Comment: I for one see one downside that bothers me. I've been in situations where I had to fall back on dialup Internet. And compression proxies are a godsend there. But they all break on HTTPS. They need to at least snoop on images so they can recompress them. Websites barely even seem to care about optimizing images, let alone providing lower quality on slower connections. Having a middleman that could fix this was nice. I hate giving this up. I hate giving up Opera Mobile, which used the same tech for cheap cellular phones. I totally get it.

Comment: @trlkly I'm pretty sure Opera Turbo mode still works on HTTPS sites (at least, there is no obvious reason why it wouldn't). They say it still works on Opera Mobile ([see here](http://www.opera.com/turbo)) and I'd imagine there would be an option to enable it on desktop.

Comment: Just because you don't understand why SSL is necessary doesn't mean there is some conspiracy afoot, these objections just don't hold water. SE logins have been secured with SSL for  years _because it's necessary_. The recent push for full site content to be covered is a step beyond that. One thing that it enables is access to content that would otherwise be blocked or censored.  For example Christian content can be hosted uncensored over HTTPS in countries where it would be easily blocked without SSL (because the ISP, country, and anybody else in the middle can't see what's being requested)!

Comment: @caleb, the conspiracy is with the Silicon Valley lobbyists and browser companies wanting to be the only ones with access to your records.  It is in their best interest that they are the only ones who can really track you.  I know perfectly well why Christianity.SE is better off being encrypted for you and I have no problem with that.