# Please don't allow computer-generated content

Tags: discussion, moderation

I've already posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389597/380389) my argument that the new "policy" by Stack Exchange violates their legal obligations and thus is invalid.

This is a separate appeal to all of the moderators across the network. Don't allow Stack Exchange to convince you to act against the best interest of your communities! If your community has agreed overwhelmingly that computer-generated content is damaging to your community, why should we start allowing it now?

Whether you outright ignore this policy or comply with it by the letter of the policy while continuing to find pretenses to delete computer-generated content, please don't allow this to destroy our communities!

Comment: Honestly, I am confused. Are we allowed to delete AI-generated answers or not? The new policy is not very clear to me. The teams-post said different things than MSE announcement, and the things I heard in chat seem to indicate we should still delete AI-generated content.

Comment: @Dharman The messaging is super unclear. One more reason not to change anything about the way we currently moderate over it.

Comment: @Dharman you are allowed to, as long as it's not because it's AI-generated content. You can do it for lacking references, being irrelevant to the question asked, being a closed question with no value, being a rehash of a previous answer, low quality based on score, etc. Being AI generated is not enough to warrant banning of the user that post them or deleted.

Comment: -> [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/178179)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt SE has refused to ban it network-wide. But we don't need them- no content can stay on SE over the concerted effort of our moderators and ordinary users. Nearly anyone can mark a post "rude or abusive" if it's the kind of time-wasting post most ChatGPT posts end up being.

Answer (score 23):

I can only speak for myself, one moderator on one site.

If Stack Overflow Inc. wants to allow AI-generated posts (which is essentially what the new policy does), then in the long run there's nothing the moderators can do.  Regardless of what you request, or users on any other SE site want, moderators will end up having to go along with the imposed policy.

To me, this is another example of the company showing that regardless of what they say, they really don't care that much about the community (ies) here and what those communities need.  That being the case, my attitude is fine, if they don't want moderator action on AI-generated content except in extreme cases (blatantly terrible or admittedly AI), then most AI-generated content will stay.

Comment: I like to think if enough of us do it, the sheer amount of work needed to micromanage us and make sure we're not taking action against computer-generated content will turn them off from doing it. Or at least doing it effectively.

Comment: I think if enough stackers banded together they would have to listen. Or not!

Comment: @BigJoe They could remove all the moderators (despite multiple promises that they *won't* over this sort of thing). Would that kill the community any faster than telling moderators we aren't allowed to use our judgment to act on things that everyone agrees are hurting our communities?

Comment: Wow, I'm going to shut my mouth then, That would literally suck if they did that. Thanks for the feedback @Chris-RegenerateResponse

Comment: There's also the impossible miracle- maybe SE will rethink this at some point in the future. At that point, it would be nice if we still have some communities that aren't drowned in a sea of crap.

Comment: @BigJoe BTW, "Stackers" is the term that Stack Exchange staff use to refer to themselves, not the community members.

Comment: They can do what they want with their platform (in the limits of whatever legal contract they had before). But we are reaching the point where we should realize that we all are also free to stop provide them content.

Comment: @Chris - Regenerate Response: They could decide tomorrow to replace moderators with AI moderation bots, like on Quora.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum They could also just shut off the servers. We can't keep them from bringing the site down if they really put their mind to it. :p

Comment: @Chris-RegenerateResponse MathOverflow can, though; the company is contractually obliged to keep enough servers running to operate an account migration system, on request.