# Why not explore the future of text generation in a more segregated fashion?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

SE.Inc has decided we are doing [LLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model) stuff now. They are burning [investment capital](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390350/348401) while doing so. Yet it appears that none of those stakeholders have successfully demanded what I imagine is perfectly feasible:
They could be doing LLM stuff in a [separate but equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plessy_v._Ferguson) place.

They could measure its value and effects independently, so the [growth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389960/348401) numbers only ever show one thing at a time. No LLM spam on the site, no tearing down things that work while evaluating things that might work in the future. Yet here we are, being <del>offered</del>[decreed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389582/what-is-the-network-policy-regarding-ai-generated-content) only a package deal. Still discussing the future of LLMs and the present of Stackexchange as if these concerns had any excuse to be [intermingled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390228/is-there-a-correlation-between-opposing-the-use-of-ai-generated-content-on-stack).

So, what excuses are there? **Why can we not [clearly differentiate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390519/348401) it from the existing sites?** I proprose that we discuss & dispel those excuses here, as another major pathway to get back to a more closely aligned [Community-](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389684/what-does-prashanth-mean-by-community-in-his-blogposts-and-how-do-the-mods-in) and other C-level perception.

To get the started, imagine this plan was among those lovely "We just did this" [announcements](/questions/tagged/announcements):

1. *SO copycat* at `llmoverflow.com` with all questions live, but none of the regular answers.
2. Bots, including [SE.Inc benchmark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425167), publish their flavour of computer-aided plagiarism there.
3. Strictly *opt-in*, users see those on SO, carefully hiding the complexity of separate instances.
4. Watch these volunteers to measure how people<sup>‡</sup> are engaging with generated answers.
5. Explore how it helps with questions so bad that even autocomplete answers seem acceptable.
6. Ask search engines how the site is performing in "user visited, but kept searching" style metrics.

As far as I can tell, nothing like the above is planned. Why not, why insist we continue disagreeing on the merits and costs of [having LLM spam over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389928/gpt-on-the-platform-data-actions-and-outcomes), when we *could* test [reaping the benefits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389744/how-could-ai-be-used-to-augment-curation-tooling) of LLM technology while still effectively [segregating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389978/if-se-wont-allow-heuristics-to-identify-ai-how-does-it-plan-on-stopping-spam-p) LLM spam?

<sub>Yes, words like *disagreeing/we* are inadequate for communication & power dynamics at play. Not the point here, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

‡ May or may not be a population currently participating in similar fashion. Comparisons would net interesting metrics.</sub>

Comment: It is difficult for humans to evaluate the quality of ChatGPT answers because they are often very well-written nonsense.

Comment: I'm all for moving all the LLM stuff far, far away from the human content. The folks who want to use it can then have a moderation-free dump of generative mishmash to play with to their heart's content, and the folks who want a curated, human SME-driven resource can keep SO as it was before when mods were able to delete obvious LLM spam. Problem solved.

Comment: No one would use it - part of the idea here would be to exploit the network's reputation for pet projects

Comment: Who would want to participate on this new site? (Admittedly, the importance of this question has been diminished due to recent events.) Many of the people who are posting these AI answers aren't interested in playing by the rules. They're only interested in Stack Overflow reputation (valuable because it unlocks privileges or looks good on a resume) or sometimes passing off their spam as a real post. And then there's apparently a bunch that don't even know AI's against the rules, which is fair enough because I ignore sidebars too.

Comment: Re *"treating reputation like a flexibly transferable asset, and observations about the finite nature of the novelty factor"*: I think you lost most of us. It isn't clear what is referred to (or it may just be word salad)

Comment: "what seems obvious to us" If there is one thing I learned that nothing is ever obvious to a group of people. There are always some for or against any given proposal no matter what it is.

Comment: @Someone-OnStrike "It is difficult for humans to evaluate the quality of ChatGPT answers because they are often very well-written nonsense." Well, who can't check the content or don't know enough shouldn't vote on content. Only if they have sufficient domain knowledge should they vote and they shouldn't just go by the looks. This is the part of where I actually like AI assistance (when it improves my language).

Comment: If AIs were human, civil rights advocates wouldn't like this question...

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Civil rights advocates should like to pay close attention to the precise line between human and AI actions, even and especially when they do *not* believe companies should once again be granted additional (e.g. copyright) privileges otherwise exclusively enjoyed by humans.

Answer (score 8):

I'm strongly opposed. As an individual contributor, the existence of any LLM project bearing the "Stack Overflow" or "Stack Exchange" branding would make me just as reluctant to continue using this site as straight up allowing LLMs on the main site. Frankly anything under the same corporate umbrella would make me uncomfortable.

My objections to LLMs are ethical in nature, and I do not want to use my labor to contribute to the positive reputation of a site which is then laundering that reputation to make LLMs trained on stolen labor look mainstream.

Comment: i mean, every "project" listed [here](https://stackoverflow.co/labs) is an LLM project bearing the "Stack Overflow" name.

Comment: So the proposal *would* make a difference to you, if only your expectation of the outcome was different? I imagine laundering that reputation works better when the level of separation lower.

Comment: @KevinB and I've been loudly opposed to both of the ones that I knew about, the formatter and the title assistant. that "chat decipher" for the Teams product is news to me and doesn't make me too happy either.

Comment: @anx even if the separated site was an abject failure, it would still be cited as evidence of the "importance of AI to the tech market." a depressing amount of the direction of the tech industry is driven by giving C-suites FOMO.

Comment: @Willa I agree, but would still like to contrast with how long we did not have (significant numbers) of electric cars. Where projects were very much separated even where under the same brand umbrellas, and thus C-suites had quite a bit of memories of past, unsuccessful, attempts before daring to aim for the mass market again.

Answer (score 8):

I unironically think this is a great idea.

In the online gaming world, there are cheaters. People who don't want to compete honestly and by their own skill, but use aimbots or other methods of input control or information gathering that gives an unfair advantage against players playing without such tools.

Most online games have detections for recognizing such tools. Some leave it up to an admin to deal with it, others outright ban those players from the server or game altogether. There's another category: bot servers.

This is a world that works just like the real thing: players can still log in, still join servers and play against other players. One tiny detail: **all players on those servers are those who are recognized as cheaters**. So everyone has the same advantages, they just don't bother the regular players anymore.

So yes, let's accept AI as a fact of life, just like cheaters, and put all GPT-generating and -accepting users together on the same site, so they don't bother others anymore.

Comment: However, in computer games, containment does address most of the concerns. The refinement of the perfect anti-cheater cheat has negligible impact. But erosion of my rights in places I do not directly participate in **still does bother me**.

Comment: I'm not so much into gaming. Are bot servers very popular?

Comment: @NoDataDump that's the point: the cheaters don't know they're on a cheaters-only server.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, @anx. I'm just opting for upholding the LLM ban and letting people who want to use LLMs to ask and answer questions do so in a walled garden.

Comment: "cheaters don't know" is a marketing bluff. One that should never have been repeated in the media, with no proof and no reason to believe it. Everyone playing online games over time learns to guess what is fair play and what is not. What could possibly make cheaters - those with more knowledge and more technical assistance - even *less* proficient in this regard?

Comment: @anx there's a whole lot of people who just buy an aimbot subscription because they want to git gud without putting in the leg work, or hand work or whatever. Perhaps they do know they're put into servers with other cheaters, perhaps they don't. CS has a trust level. New users get pitted against other new users, who may or may not be cheaters. The point is, bad analogies side, that I'd say GPTers are a fact of life just like cheaters. Instead of ignoring their existence, let them fight it out among themselves.

Comment: How exactly would you identify the cheaters? How exactly would they get out of the cheaters' purgatory if they wanted to? How would the purgatory be inmplemented; a separate copy of the site with a slowly diverging content base as old content gets edited etc? (Who would want to pay for that?)

Answer (score -6):

> Why can we not clearly differentiate it from the existing sites?

Another option is allowing AI-generated answers on regular stack exchange sites but hide them by default and have an option for users to display them if they want to see AI-generated answers. (And just like for any answers, suspend the users if they post too many incorrect answers)

Answer (score -7):

**A separate site appears *NOT* desirable, not even for the company, for the following reasons:**

**#1** The cost is not justified if there is little to no use for the new site. [Nobody would use such a thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390536/why-not-explore-the-future-of-text-generation-in-a-more-segregated-fashion#comment1304392_390536)

However, If someone was burning through my money to make things happen that nobody would use, I would want to to know. I would want that (lack of) interest measurable in isolation.

**#2** It is easier to launder the reputation of the Great Stack Overflow if the level of separation is lower. A separate site might not be perceived as quite "part of the network" as dumping experiments right into SO.

However, using the opt-on mechanism from my thought experiment above would make that separation to remain in the only reasonable place - where people want it. Besides, outside observers and the media are well acquainted with the idea of a single company offering multiple products, so reputation is not exactly an asset one can flexibly transfer from "Stackoverflow for Humans" to "Stackoverflow against Humans".

**#3** Some of the uses for AI would simply not exist on a separate site, e.g. it would not be possible [earn rep and unlock privileges on the actual site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390536/why-not-explore-the-future-of-text-generation-in-a-more-segregated-fashion#comment1304409_390536)

However, a separate site would help produce a more realistic picture of *organic* (not just trying to cheat) engagement.

**#4** Even with a separate site, we would still have LLM spam on the main site. You would not be truly separating LLM content.

However, in dealing with that spam we would not need to take into consideration that those spammers are exploring technology the company is highly interested in. Without being scared of suspending the most interesting users, that seemed to lead to *manageable* levels of stuff posted to the wrong site.

Comment: _"an argument in favour of moving LLM stuff away"_ is not an argument in favor of implementing LLM stuff elsewhere, by SE. It's an argument in favor of staying away from LLMs

Comment: @Cerbus Edited out. I am still working under the premise that the [future](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/04/17/community-is-the-future-of-ai/) has not yet been fundamentally reconsidered.

Comment: I think you missed the point of what I (and JG) said. How would your idea lead to "No LLM spam on the site"? Most of the people who are currently posting AI answers on SO aren't going to move to your new LLM answer site, and if you asked them to they'd lie that they weren't using AI. (Maybe the problem is I don't care about the "growth numbers" for AI and just want us to have user generated Q&A sites like we did before the suspension of AI suspension.)