# Add the [featured] tag to the "Updates to Privacy Policy (September 2021)" post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, privacy, featured-tag

**Update**:

On [22/10/2021 at 16:53:37Z](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/370216/timeline#history_53659589-486c-42a5-a695-e950ac50b040), the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag was removed from [the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370216). So, the post had the tag for 23 days 20 hours 42 minutes 15 seconds [totally](https://www.calculator.net/time-calculator.html?tcday1=12&tchour1=21&tcminute1=50&tcsecond1=27&Op=%2B&tcday2=10&tchour2=22&tcminute2=51&tcsecond2=48&tcday3=&tchour3=&tcminute3=&tcsecond3=&ctype=1&x=100&y=22) (12 days, 21 hours, 50 minutes and 27 seconds + [10 days, 22 hours, 51 minutes and 48 seconds](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=11&m1=10&y1=2021&d2=22&m2=10&y2=2021&h1=18&i1=01&s1=49&h2=16&i2=53&s2=37)).

It is a matter of concern that the company does not wanna follow the precedent of 27 days, 7 hours, 55 minutes and 30 seconds or at max 30 days. Also, Rosie said "feature three posts at a time". I don't think the tag needed to be removed now as only two posts are featured now. Anyway, I don't think the post will be featured any more.

Stack Exchange, please follow the good precedents and try to set better precedents if possible. Please.

---

The [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag was added to [Updates to Privacy Policy (September 2021)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370216) on [24/09/2021 at 21:44:45Z](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/370216/timeline#history_4967e661-a74f-4960-94d6-68b53c87f22d). The tag was removed from the post on [07/10/2021 at 19:35:12Z](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/370216/timeline#history_64319260-47c2-479e-afa8-5ddfbad00439). So the post had the tag for [12 days, 21 hours, 50 minutes and 27 seconds](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=24&m1=09&y1=2021&d2=07&m2=10&y2=2021&h1=21&i1=44&s1=45&h2=19&i2=35&s2=12).

Since no email was sent to Stack Exchange users regarding the fact that changes have been made to the [Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy), it is a matter of concern that the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag has been removed from the post just under 2 weeks. The least that Stack Exchange could do is to have the tag until the [Community bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) [removes it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281797) such that maximum number of people can be aware about the fact that changes have been made to the Privacy Policy.

Let's take a look at the precedent. The [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag was removed from [Stack Exchange Privacy Policy Update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292062) after [27 days, 7 hours, 55 minutes and 30 seconds](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=8&m1=3&y1=2017&d2=4&m2=4&y2=2017&h1=15&i1=35&s1=34&h2=23&i2=31&s2=04).

I [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1237220) about this, but I did not get any response.

I request the Stack Exchange staff to add the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to the post immediately and let the tag stay until the Community bot removes it.

Comment: They probably did that because there are 3 other posts currently with the tag - do you have a suggestion for which to kick off the list?

Comment: Since [Version labels for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370640) and [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568) are posts related to things which affect the SE users, these posts can have the tag. The tag can be removed from [CM escalations - How we got the queue back down to zero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370442). We have no other options I feel. BTW, I don't wanna discredit the hard work done by the CMs to get the queue down to 0. @bobble

Comment: @bobble Arguably, that's a matter of publishing too many things in the same month. Stop doing that.

Comment: Do note that it's weekend, so no response to a comment after one day does not mean they won't get to it.

Comment: @Glorfindel I certainly agree with you, but since the Privacy Policy (which is a very important legal agreement) has already come into effect, it is a matter which needs immediate attention.

Comment: There's a banner at the top for anyone who hasn't dismissed it ... can you explain why a second link in the sidebar is necessary?

Comment: @Catija I cannot see the top banner in incognito. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5naid.png. Also, people notice stuff mentioned in the sidebar in a keen manner than compared to the top bar which can be easily dismissed (probably by accident).

Comment: @Catija I just tested, and it seems the banner isn't shown to logged-out users. (But that's more an argument for fixing that rather than featuring it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I re-added the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370216). For context, it was featured before but we try to only feature three posts at a time; so we remove the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag from older posts when we have newer items to feature.

I removed the [CM escalation post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370442) from **Featured on Meta** sidebar because a lot of people have read that now. When we do have something new to feature in the future, the tag [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/370216/timeline#history_6920501e-c523-4054-b7f6-066bfb807263) will be removed once again, just as a heads up.

Comment: I guess I lost my 50 rep because of lack of patience https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/370707/timeline#history_ae6f337d-1847-4a6e-88f4-446179aad9de 

Comment: Rosie, I have a request: at least, please wait for [14 days 10 hours 5 minutes 3 seconds](https://www.calculator.net/time-calculator.html?tcday1=27&tchour1=7&tcminute1=55&tcsecond1=30&Op=-&tcday2=12&tchour2=21&tcminute2=50&tcsecond2=27&tcday3=&tchour3=&tcminute3=&tcsecond3=&ctype=1&x=84&y=37) before you (any staff) remove the featured tag from https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370216; at max, please wait till the Community bot removes it.

Comment: @JamesA haha.. true 

Comment: Rosie, "*but we try to only feature __three__ posts at a time*".... [maybe not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0f7a.png)