# Maximum number of posts that can be featured in MSE

Tags: support, featured-tag

What is the maximum number of posts that can be featured in Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: Pretty obvious there is no limit. I think the latest four will be displayed in sidebar, but system will let even 1000 questions to have the tag.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack We never know till staff or mods test it.

Comment: If it was limited it would have been written or said somewhere already. The limit is only in the sidebar.

Answer (score -7):

[Rosie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/943183/rosie), Community Manager, [said this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370769/):

> ... but we try to only feature three posts at a time;...

But, as of writing this answer, 4 posts were featured in MSE:

[image]

Comment: Well, she did say "try". So in extreme cases like what we have these days, there can be more. It's not a hard limit or policy.