# Example newsletter popup is empty

Tags: bug, newsletter

On some pages you can see "Love this site?" banner:

> [image: lovesite]

You can also see the example from [your user profile preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/).

Clicking on "example newsletter" link leads to open empty popup window:

> [image: empty]

To see the data you need to open the [example newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=meta.stackexchange.com) link in a new tab:

> [image: newtab]

Despite the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) on [the answer in the main HTTPS roadmap question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292206/339911) problem is still exists.

Comment: Can't find a page with the newsletter ad on now to check, but at a guess it's probably because the newsletter is on the main domain which is still HTTP, so can't be embedded in the now HTTPS site here

Comment: @Cai just try to refresh current page several times. But avoid to make it to quickly to prevent  [tempopary ban](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x3B4b.png).

Comment: @Cai more safe way is to open different questions from the homepage. Each 10-14 page contains such banner. Also be sure to have AdBlock disabled.

Comment: Found it after a lot of refreshes... then realised you can get to it from your preferences :)

Comment: @Cai oh... true :) Feel free to edit the question. I'm on the phone now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (See [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292206/307988))

---

The example newsletter is loaded as an iframe from the main domain (stackexchange.com) over HTTP; since MSE (this domain) is now served over HTTPS, the HTTP request is blocked. You can see the mixed content warning in the console:

> [image]

From [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/307988):

> This is for Q&A. Area 51, Chat, and stackexchange.com (the main site) have a separate set of concerns and code we'll address after Q&A

So the main domain will be switched after the Q&A, at which point this should be fixed. Seems the newsletter page itself does support HTTPS though, so changing the link to HTTPS fixes it:

> [image]