# Why does the meta.site to site.meta edit by Community show up more than once?

Tags: bug, edits, ssl

We've just switched from meta.site.SE to site.meta.SE, and Community♦ is going around editing the links. I went and looked at [the revision history](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/10718/revisions) of one such post, and was surprised to the edit show three times:

[image]

Why is it showing three times?

---

This *might* only apply to SFF; I don't see it three times on [Puzzling.meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5839/revisions) or [Literature.meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/615/revisions), but I am seeing it on [other](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/10699/revisions) [SFF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/10509/revisions) [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/6582/revisions) [posts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/10687/revisions). Some of those have it twice, one has it four times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We enabled https on most of the child meta sites today, and as part of that, we did a rewrite of the URLs in post bodies.

[Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time)

Looks like the code for rewriting the URLs has a bug, which we'll have to track down and squash before running it on the main sites.

Comment: Now I'm getting "too many redirects" on child meta sites..

Comment: @ɥʇǝS https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/842448394656350208

Comment: @AdamLear Aha. Disabling HTTPS everywhere "fixed" it. Hopefully that PR gets merged soon.