# Why was I unsubscribed from the Meta.SE newsletter?

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter

I subscribe to the weekly newsletter on several sites, including here on Meta.SE.  My Meta newsletter always comes on the same day as two others, so when I got the other two today but not this one, I went digging.  Apparently I didn't get it last week either, but didn't notice then.  It's not in my spam trap.

I then went to the subscriptions page on my network profile and found that my Meta subscription was missing.  I've now resubscribed, but how did I become unsubscribed in the first place?

Comment: Bet it's related to the ssl switch. My subscription is also gone.

Comment: I *almost* ended this with "should I blame HTTPS?", but I don't quite see how it'd be connected.  Thanks for the info that it's not just me, though -- that does sound like a bug, then.

Comment: Can't really know, but I doubt it is a coincidence, as MSE is the only site that went into full HTTPS support, as whole.

Comment: First-world problem: after resubscribibg, my newsletters are going to come on the wrong day.  (I'll get over it;  I just didn't know that varied on a single site. )

Comment: Can we update http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ to say "No, it's probably just https"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pushing a fix for old subscriptions right now, and will fix up anyone who subscribed between the migration and now shortly afterwards.

Due to an old system I haven't quite killed yet (working on it), there was duplication on the SE.com site, and Newsletters were defaulting to the newer site entry, not finding your old subscription.

Subscriptions are now synced up and I'll be correcting TagSets (Question Filters) next.