# Unknown site on Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

[image]

When I select the unknown site (i.e. the meta sites) the app crashes.

I have a Samsung Note 5 and version 1.0.89 of the app.

Comment: Just click on edit and after a moment press back and tell me if solved?

Comment: @Pandya That appears to solve the problem.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292460)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.94 which is going live as we speak.

We now look for pre-https migration `meta.*` URLs stored in the pinned sites, and if we find any we do the same refresh-with-site that occurs when you hit "Edit".

Comment: Interestingly enough, my meta sites simply disappeared from that menu seemingly for no reason.

Comment: @MattSamuel hmm, after hitting the "Edit" button? The pinned sites list gets superseded by any changes made on web to the "Your Communities" accessible under the SE icon in the top bar. When you click on the SE icon in the top bar, do you see the meta sites?

Comment: On the app? I don't see anything like that.

Comment: @MattSamuel no sorry I mean -- the app's sidebar pinned sites are synced with the desktop web's "Your Communities" in the top bar, and if there are conflicts when syncing the two the one from the web wins. I would guess that's what happened here.