# Renamed sites confuse (and crash) app

Tags: bug, android-app

On my device (running Stack Exchange Android app v1.0.95), the Stack Exchange sites sidebar lists "**Unknown Site cogsci**" with the default Stack Exchange icon.

[image: Screenshot showing incomplete migration]

<sup>(Sorry, no freehand circle to highlight the problem entry. It's in the middle, between Community Building and Biology.)</sup>

When I tap this icon, **the app crashes** with (what I believe is) a null pointer exception.

I believe that the site formerly known as Cognitive Science (that is, `cogsci.stackexchange.com`) was renamed or otherwise migrated sometime in the past few months.

I see a twofold problem:

1. It looks like the app missed this migration, leaving my sidebar pointing to a non-existent site.
2. In addition, the app crashes when visiting non-existent sites (instead of showing "site not found" or similar).

Comment: It was renamed to "Psychology & Neuroscience", but it was the URL change (to https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) that causes this bug. The [same thing happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292482/323179) when the meta URL scheme was changed.

Comment: @Laurel and when a Beta site is closed