# Meta sites infinite redirect loop

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, redirection, domain-names

Since yesterday, meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com redirects to mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com.  At the same time, my browser (Chrome) goes into a redirect loop, so I cannot visit the site.

[image]

If I try to visit the site in incognito mode, then all is fine, so I thought that (as the message suggests) I just need to clear some cookies.  But after clearing all cookies with "stackexchange" in the name, it still doesn't work.

Short of deleting *all* cookies (which I really do not want to do), how can I fix this?

Comment: what browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @gnat Chrome on OS X.

Comment: Others have been complaining of the same too BTW (in chatrooms), but I guess they were willing to just clear all cookies. If I can, I would like to avoid getting logged out of all sites I use regularly ...  However, if there is no simple way, I will just clear everything.

Comment: thanks, looks like this is [supported configuration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/165773)

Comment: Same problem, been happening for a few hours now, waiting for the SE people to fix it. I have tried on several computers and browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to fix this on my end by disabling my "HTTPS Everywhere" browser plugin. Check for this plugin and also check all browser security and DNS settings.

Hopefully the sites will work fine with HTTPS Everywhere in the future, as StackExchange has recently [migrated their sites for HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) and so some issues are to be expected. There is [a bug open on HTTPS Everywhere's GitHub page](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/pull/9110) if you would like to give additional information.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer!  I had that extension too.