# Will [meta.X.se] magic links stop working in favor of [X.meta.se]?

Tags: support, comments, magic-links

When I'm here, on Meta.se, I often guide people to specific child metas using the [magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92060/273503) syntax `[meta.foo.se]`.

For example, in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292915/duplicate-question#comment951594_292915), I typed `[meta.math.se]` and it automagically expanded in the rendered comment to [Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com).

With the [pending URL scheme change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/273503) from http://meta.foo.se/ to https://foo.meta.se, should I correspondingly adjust my comments to use `[foo.meta.se]`? Is that the best practice?

Will `[meta.foo.se]` continue to work, in case my muscle memory overrides my thinkbox?

<sub>To be clear, in case it's confusing anyone, I'm not asking whether `[foo.meta.se]` will be implemented: it already is. The questions I'd like answered are above: the sentences ending with question marks.</sub>

Comment: Testing: `[meta.math.se]`: [meta.math.se] ; `[math.meta.se]`:  [math.meta.se] . Looks like they both work.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I didn't ask if [foo.meta.se] would be implemented, I asked whether it is better to use that than [meta.foo.se], and if [meta.foo.se] would continue to be supported.

Comment: They both work. Just tested as you did.

Comment: @PatrickHofman These are the questions I'd like answered, and not any others you might be thinking of: *Should I correspondingly adjust my comments to use `[foo.meta.se]`? Is that the best practice?  Will `[meta.foo.se]` continue to work?*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The old syntax is already a heavy habit for some people, and we don't want to abruptly affect their commenting habits on our site. Both syntaxes work, and it's unlikely we'd ever drop the old syntax. Just having two syntaxes for accessing per-site Metas doesn't exactly harm anything. So use whichever one you'd like.

Comment: Why do we have to swap the domains?

Comment: @Ooker The domains in the URL are being swapped [to better supper HTTPS everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/273503), and improve security for the site and all its users. The domains in the magic links are being swapped (well, *support* being swapped)  to march the swapped domains in the URL.

Comment: @DanBron why do swapping the domains improve security for the sites? A quick google doesn't answer me

Comment: @Ooker Read the post I linked to, this comment chain isn't the place to recapitulate the whole thing. Short story is to facilitate getting SSL certificates for all the meta sites (because getting a cert for `https://*.foo.bar.com` is straightforward as opposed to getting a bunch of different ones to secure `https://foo.*.bar.com`).