# Magic links not working for alternative URLs on meta

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, magic-links

In chat just now, I was trying to mention some meta sites using the magic links. Just as `[maths.se]` and `[fantasy.se]` and `[thefinalfrontier.se]` should (and do!) render as links to Mathematics SE, Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE, and Space Exploration SE respectively, the associated meta links `[maths.meta.se]` and `[fantasy.meta.se]` and `[thefinalfrontier.meta.se]` should render as links to the associated meta sites. But they don't.

[image: screenshot of bug happening]

Comment: [maths.meta.se] and [fantasy.meta.se] and [thefinalfrontier.meta.se] <--- yup, same bug in comments as well as chat

Comment: If you type `maths.stackexchange.com` into your browser you get redirected to `math.stackexchange.com`, but `maths.meta.stackexchange.com` just gives you the error panda.

Comment: Have the metas ever worked? Because I don't think they have... I regularly want to link to MSO and can't. See: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6640900#6640900

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292916/273503 .

Comment: @Catija There's a feature request to get `[meta.so]` working at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274240/215590

Comment: I have no trouble using `[meta.gis.se]` to link to [meta.gis.se] and `[meta.math.se]` works when pointing to [meta.math.se] too.

Comment: @PolyGeo But `[gis.se]` is the master URL, not an alias. This is about alternate URLs not redirecting for meta.

Comment: I'd missed that distinction - but I'm keen to see all expected magic links working so have upvoted your question.

Comment: This seems to be affecting the full urls, which is probably why the magic links don't work. [http://fantasy.meta.stackexchange.com/](http://fantasy.meta.stackexchange.com/) gives a site not found error. It may be better to raise this as a different bug, as the root is likely the meta URL aliases, not the magic links.