# A bug in the responses count?

Tags: support, profile-page, responses

I just witnessed what I presume was a bug in the count of responses in my profile on [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

> [image]

I do not have more than a thousand new responses.  Has something changed in the formula used to produce this number?  Was this an isolated glitch of some sort?

Note: I click it fairly regularly so I don't think I've ever seen it over 100 before.

Comment: The number show the **new** responses. What was the number before? Did it jump from 0 to 1096 in one day? I have 14383 here because I simply never click it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I click it fairly regularly so I don't think I've ever seen it over 100 before.

Comment: Are many of them 'revisions' from the Community user? Any post that contained a link to another question/answer will have been converted to HTTPS in the last two days, and is shown in the responses tab (though fortunately not the global inbox), and you have enough posts on Mathematica for 1096 to be a reasonable number of edited posts. (see [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/336144))

Comment: @Aurora0001 that is it. I have over 800 reponses here on MSE and that are mainly Community edits:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rri0L.png feel free to post that as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently, the main sites (except Stack Overflow) [moved to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/336144). Any links in posts that go to other questions/answers using HTTP were automatically converted to HTTPS by the community user, [as you can see for rene's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294768/a-bug-in-the-responses-count?noredirect=1#comment956235_294768).

You currently have 3,309 posts on Mathematica.SE, so it seems feasible that around 1,000 of your posts contained links to other pages on the site and were automatically edited by the Community user.

You can check this by going to the **revisions** tab of your responses. If there are lots of edits from the Community user, that should explain the issue. The edits should appear to come at around midday (UTC) 2017-04-13.

Nothing to be concerned about though—this was, of course, a one time event, and viewing the tab should clear the counter. Fortunately for you, the edits didn't go to the global inbox, or else I suspect there would be far more bug reports!

Comment: Yeah luckily those were non bumping edits as well, so it didn't clutter the sites question lists. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Indeed, but it can still make meta on smaller sites [look like Community has taken over](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/) (only about 7 of the posts were modified by a human on the front page, and only 1 non-diamond!)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.  I've been rather inactive recently and I hadn't noticed the Community activity.