# Area 51 proposals used as sidebar advertising cause security warnings

Tags: bug, area-51, advertising, ssl

For example, Christianity Stack Exchange is running [an ad for the Hebrew Language proposal](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6230/214). This causes Firefox to give security warnings.

> Connection is Not Secure
>
> Parts of this page are not secure (such as images).

Answer (score 5):

You just need to update the community ad post to use the HTTPS image. i.e...

```
https://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/102005.png
    ^
```

Not sure why the automated script didn't catch those, but the HTTPS ad images work so it's a simple fix. The links generated by Area 51 [have been updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292074/307988) so this shouldn't be an issue with any future posts, I guess there may be a few existing ads that need updating though.

Comment: I've edited that by hand, now. But I'm still calling this a bug, as it should have been either edited automatically or excluded from the rotation until it was edited (or both).

Comment: Sure, it *should* have been caught by the automated script