# Links to meta in custom close reasons still use old meta URLs

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, close-reasons, ssl, custom-close-reasons

Strongly related to [the continued use of non-HTTPS links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295054/239016), if a custom close reason features a link to meta, that link will be

1. Using HTTP instead of HTTPS
2. Using the old format for URLs on meta, `meta.stack.stackexchange.com` instead of `stack.meta.stackexchange.com`.

For an example on a specific stack, see
[Minor technical issues with off-topic close box](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11002/19561) over on SF&F.

---

This seems to have been fixed on SFF. Perhaps it was fixed on *all* Stacks?