# Old combined flair links were not updated from http to https

Tags: bug, ssl, combined-flair

E.g. if you have an old post that contains a global SE site flair:

```
<a href="http://stackexchange.com/users/947951">
  <img src="http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/947951.png" >
</a>
```

The process that updated http links to https missed them.

Unlike the links within the individual sites that do work well: `https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/8.png`

[This edit history](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/105/revisions) is relevant.

Comment: What script are you talking about? Who wrote it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The script that runs over all SE sites and changes `http:` links to `https:` ones: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/

Comment: I see. It wasn't clear in the first revision, edited now to clarify even better. (it's not just a "script", it's more commonly known as "process", as far as I know.)