# Finding a closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I saw a question on a site. I wrote an answer but before I could submit my answer the question was closed, then I moved on and closed the tab. There was no comment indicating the question was a duplicate, so I don't think that was the reason. I forget the details of the explanation, but I wanted to visit the question again to understand what the problem was. However, I can't find the comments I posted; is it possible the question was deleted?

Should I be able to find the question? I saw it about 4-6 hours ago. Is it possible to get it re-opened? It was not the best question but I believed it was worth answering.

Comment: This should have been asked on Stack Overflow Meta

Comment: If this is the question you're referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642329/c-sharp-what-are-the-different-ways-of-implementing-a-simple-markup-parser-witho , the first comment provides a pretty clear description of why they thought it was too broad.

Comment: @Midavalo, I am sorry. I did not realize there are more than one meta. What should I do?

Comment: @BradLarson, yes, that is it. I apologize for not finding it. I will bookmark it. I am not sure about the "very broad and opinion based". I disagree. I think the people voting to close it are equally opinionated. There are relatively specific answers, in the sense of a specific piece of software that is appropriate.

Comment: I've made an attempt to salvage this question and voted to reopen it (although feel free to roll back the edit if you think it was too much). I tried to remove the question/site-specific stuff and focus on the questions that were actually asked in the post itself, which mostly regarded finding a closed question. If you want to debate the merits of the specific question, as mentioned already, hit up MSO for that.

Comment: I don't know if I can get the points back by deleting it but the down-votes indicate that people want it deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Just responding to various bits that aren't SO-specific:

> I can't find the comments I posted; is it possible the question was deleted?
>
> ...
>
> Should I be able to find the question? I saw it about 4-6 hours ago.

It is always possible for questions to be deleted. However, here are a few tips for finding posts you've participated in assuming they weren't deleted:

- Check your browser history, especially if you know the rough time range.
- Check the [Activity → All Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2392247/user34660?tab=activity) tab on your profile page. Your comments, votes, etc. will be there, with links. Knowing the time range can help you narrow this down too, and remembering e.g. some words you typed in a comment can help you search the page with your browser's text search feature.
- Check your inbox on the top bar. If you received e.g. recent comment replies, they'll still be there, with a link. The *Activity → Responses* page on your profile can give you similar info.
- If the question is older and you remember certain things about it you can also hit up [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com), which is updated weekly. For example, [a simple comment search](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/663978?Text=flex+and+bison&UserId=2392247).

If the question was deleted, these won't yield results (well, if it's in your browser history you'll get a "question not found" page or something, which means that it was deleted).

> Is it possible to get it re-opened?

If you have [3000 or more rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), you'll have the privilege to [cast reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Otherwise the only thing you can do is express your desire in a comment and hope somebody notices.

> I am sorry. I did not realize there are more than one meta.

Also, if you want to discuss specific details of a particular question, you should post that on the site's meta. MSE is sort of the general meta for the whole network. Every site has its own meta, which can be accessed through the community dropdown on the top bar, or generally by putting a `meta.` in front of the URL (well, technically, [the `meta` is the second component in the URLs now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time), but the old ones still work and it's moot for MSO). MSO is at https://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I could have tried my browsing history. I don't like how Edge shows history but I could have. As for  Activity → All Actions, I did look at my activity; I just missed seeing the "All Actions". As for finding the Stackoverflow meta, I searched the Stackoverflow home page for "meta" and only found this one. I now see what you mean by "community dropdown"; I often have no idea what an icon is for. Oh, and the "meta" part is what is called the "computer" (or something close to that) part of an URL.