# Example newsletter popup displaying as empty page from the edit profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, newsletter

In the [Edit Profile & Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) -> **Preferences**, under the **Newsletter** section, the URL for the **see an example newsletter** is still as `http://` only. Clicking on the link it opens a blank popup window.

There is a same kind of issue was reported [for the side bar and it was fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292206/312043). In the same way it need to be updated with `https://` in the **Edit Profile & Settings** tab.

This issue is in the all of the Stack Exchange sites edit profile.

Screenshots for reference:

> [image: Newsletter link]

Clicking on the link, it opens a blank popup screen.

> [image: Blank Example newsletter]

Receiving the following errors in the browser console:

**Google Chrome Version : 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)**

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=meta.stackexchange.com&suppressPromotion=true'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**Mozilla Firefox : 54.0b13 (32-bit)**

> Blocked loading mixed active content “https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=meta.stackexchange.com&suppressPromotion=true”