# Inbox notifications link to Area 51 using HTTPS

Tags: bug, area-51, notifications, global-inbox, ssl

As indicated in "*[Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time#comment948631_292074)*", HTTPS support for Area 51 is currently incomplete. Certain page elements fail to load on HTTPS, such as notifications and captchas.

Despite this, links in the notification bar directs users to `https://area51.stackexchange.com.` instead of the expected `http://area51.stackexchange.com/`

[image: Notification bar]

[image: Linked URL using HTTPS]

**Shouldn't links to Area 51 should be using HTTP until the site fully supports HTTPS?**