# Editor preview resolves title to HTTP links but rendered post does not

Tags: bug, editor, ssl, markdown-rendering, markdown-preview

The editor and the actual rendering of a post differ in their treatment of post link title expansions for non-HTTPS links. For example, the following:

- HTTPS: [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time)
- HTTP: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time

Yields this in the preview:

> [image]

But currently yields this in the actual post:

> [image]

The correct behavior should *probably* be link expansion in both cases, but more importantly, no matter what the outcome is, the preview should match the results.

Comment: Reported on MSO today: [SO links do not render like they do in the editor preview](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350147/616460)

Comment: Woo boy this was confusing to experience.