# SEDE magic columns (and site://) do not use HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, ssl

Post links generated via the SEDE magic columns (e.g. `[Post Link]`, `[Comment Link]`, etc.) as well as `site://` provide HTTP links, but should provide [HTTPS links instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058).

[Example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/678825):

```sql
select
  (select top 1 id from posts where closeddate is null) [Post Link],
  (select top 1 id from comments) [Comment Link],
  (select top 1 id from users) [User Link],
  (select top 1 id from suggestededits) [Suggested Edit Link],
  concat('site://q/', (select top 1 id from posts where closeddate is null))
```

Generates:

```html
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px">
    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 text">
        <a href="http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/35887">...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1 text">
        <a href="http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/33328">...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2 text">
        <a href="http://anime.stackexchange.com/users/-1">...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3 text">
        <a href="http://anime.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1">...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4 text">
        <a href="http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/35887">...</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, this currently makes copy + pasting links from SEDE into posts [a bit clunky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296628/editor-preview-resolves-title-to-http-links-but-rendered-post-does-not).

Comment: (just as a general FYI, I am following these; will get to them after I'm done the election stats site reboot I'm working on)

Comment: I checked and I think It needs this update in the DataExplorer db: `update sites
set Url = replace(Url,'http://', 'https://') 
where Url like 'http://%';`

Answer (score 4):

This looks to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed); SEDE seems to be available only over HTTPS right now, and the magic links have been HTTPSed:

[image]