# Chat links to Meta sites have been rewritten with invalid HTTPS

Tags: bug, chat, ssl

Way back in 2015, [a feed bot posted a link to a meta question in a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/23923373/history). The link was, in those pre-HTTPS days, `http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/`. However, if you click on it, you are not brought to `http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/` (which would redirect); nor are you brought to `https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/` (which is the new location). Instead, you are brought to `https://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/`, which throws invalid certificate errors.

Obviously the link was correct at the time of posting, and has been rewritten incorrectly since.

Comment: Hmm. It links to [Why was the question about reconciling wrongs closed?](//meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5680) for me - which loads without problems in Firefox.

Comment: Seems to fail in chrome as he described (I only have canary installed), and vivaldi, so I guess it might be browser specific. What versions of the browsers in question are in use might be handy here

Comment: Well, the link is the link. @JourneymanGeek. The only browser-specific thing is how they respond to certificate errors. It should fail on all browsers: if it works for you, your browser is insecure.