# Questions migrated from the meta site get the wrong link to the original question

Tags: bug, migration, ssl

See for example [Why is there a module for version 9 of core?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89469/why-is-there-a-drupal-9-version-of-a-module) migrated to *Drupal Answers* from its meta site. The link given in *migrated from meta.drupal.stackexchange.com Oct 19 '13 at 16:40* points to https://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/2703/revisions instead of https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2703/revisions.

> [image: screenshot]

Furthermore, when following the link, Chrome gives two errors: *Your connection is not private* and *NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID*.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Technically, when it was migrated, the link was correct. The problem here is that the system hasn't updated those links. New migrations don't have this problem.

Comment: @Catija That is correct. Links in the posts have been changed, though, through an edit of the Community user.

Comment: For you as a mod, is that a post notice on that specific question? Or is that a system generated notice? For [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/drupal/query/775511) it does look like it.

Comment: @rene It's the usual system notice I always see in migrated questions, in the site where the question is migrated. I am not sure what is the difference between a post notice and a system generated notice. For me, all the notices are system generated.

Comment: Well, there is some difference between when you lock a question (or when a question has a bounty) and the one on migrated question then. The former you can remove (edit?), the latter you can't, right?

Comment: @rene Oh... Yes, that is correct. I cannot edit the notice I am referring, in the same way I cannot edit the notice for a question closed as too broad.

Comment: @Catija. Nope. When it was migrated, the link was `http://`, not `https://`. And the `http://` link would still work, as a redirect. It should have been left as it was (HTTP), or updated properly (HTTPS and new domain name). [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297042).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed: Now the message I read on [Why is there a module for version 9 of core?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89469/why-is-there-a-module-for-version-9-of-core) is the following one.

> migrated from [drupal.meta.stackexchange.com](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2703/revisions) Oct 19 '13 at 16:40

The link is valid and it doesn't cause any error in the browser.