# area 51 not safe

Tags: bug, chat, area-51

<strike>Area 51 gave me this:</strike>

[image: urrm, what?]

which is weird, since I got there by navigating to a user's profile (which was also "unsafe"), then edited the url (to the one in the above image).

some info that might be useful:

[image: freehand circle says it all]

does the freehand circle say it all?

---

## Ok, so the problem is different

The problem is that from the chats, links to profiles on a51's Meta are still to `discussion.area51.stackexchange.com` (or whatever the link is).

Comment: The URL changed to: [`https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/`](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/). Curious, from which page/place you are getting the `https://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com` URL?

Comment: @Arulkumar oh. good to know. when did that happen? if so, then I think I know the problem...

Comment: @ItamarG3 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time

Comment: thanks, @rene... I changed the question...

Comment: Always wear protection when visiting Area51.

Comment: The reason of the cert failure is that the certificate has to be registered ($$$) whose cost increases by the count of the certified domains. Furthermore, the SE has many sites, and the domain list field in the certs is limited (although they could use multiple certs, but it would cost yet more $$$ for them, and poor ie6 users from winxp would still get the warnings). If you go to the old address of the discuss.a51, your browser will get a redirect to your new one. *This redirect request can't happen on a properly certified channel, this is why you got this warning*.

Comment: @peterh there is HTTPS all over SE by now (except in chat). There is https support for Area51 and its meta aka discussion zone. The URL just changed, and they forgot to change the link to point to it. It's a minor bug, probably nobody on SE saw the bug reports yet. They might see them in 6-8 weeks, or not. Until then, people can manually put the correct URL and be safe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard 6-8 weeks seems a reasonable amount.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard 6 to 8 weeks seems "reasonable", and proved to be "optimistic" since, as of 2018-01-08, it still is a problem.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver true. Make it 6-8 years.... but more likely it will never be fixed as SE does not care about Area 51 enough to even look at its bugs, at this point.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Maybe the little green men can adjust it for us. :) They did, however, get A51 into the HTTPS push, finally. And that ends up causing the problem we now see. One step forward, two steps back..... Devs must hate to look at A51 code.

Comment: @Gypsy well, whatever Nick did to add that ssl to Area 51 most likely did not involve any code change. He left that for other developers, who probably don't exist. :/

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Which reminds me of the comment he put in SE source (something with "It's left as an exercise for the reader..."). Can't find it now.

Comment: @ItamarG3 think Adam said that, not Nick. :/

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard oh. I was looking for the picture. Can't remember to what it was related...