# Should we force users to post links to SE sites in HTTPS?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks, ssl

[Network-wide HTTPS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/) is a good idea. SE devs have been working hard to replace existing HTTP links to HTTPS, and they even batch replaced links in existing posts with the Community bot on May 20<sup>[citation needed]</sup>. However, users are still allowed to post links to SE sites in HTTP, like the one in the beginning.

I suppose we should disallow users to post links to SE sites in HTTP, or alternatively we can change them automatically upon submitting posts (change source) or upon rendering (change rendered result).

```
http://(.*(stackexchange|stackoverflow|superuser|serverfault|askubuntu|stackapps)\.com|.*mathoverflow\.net)
```

Possible problems:

- If we change the Markdown source automatically during post submission, we may accidentally run over [the length limit](/a/176447/350567) for Markdown source of posts.

Answer (score 2):

Let me ask you two questions in return, the first being far more important than the second.

- **How do you get a link to a Stack Exchange website or post in the first place?**

> and what protocol does it (already) have?

- What if I want to post a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) about HTTP links like [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299181/295232)?

<sub>(yes, I believe this qualifies as an answer why this *shouldn't* be implemented)</sub>

Comment: I know, but who *types* an URL? People just copy it from the browser's address bar, or the 'share' link underneath each post. These are already HTTPS.

Comment: What's wrong with get?

Comment: Well, in rare and weird cases, people may obtain a link from another source or and old (outdated) source, for example another site on the internet or their own "clipboards".

Comment: That's true (and when linking to a site, I sometimes type the URL as well). But that's relatively rare, as is spare SO developer time. I just think it's not worthwhile to implement.