# Convert http links to https in tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, ssl

As part of the [migration to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time), a bot rewrote `http://` links pointing inside the Stack Exchange network to `https://`. This bot only ran on questions and answers.

Please run the bot on tag wikis as well. (By now some have been updated manually, but there are plenty of remaining `http://` links.)

Comment: Wow, thanks! What possibilities, to get "research assisant" badges, first some hundred of reps, and so on! Tyvm! :-)

Comment: I wrote [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/715177/tag-wikis-with-internal-http-links) query to find the tag wikis with internal http:// link...

Comment: @peterh If you want to waste your time doing the work of a bot, fine, but **do it only on sites where you have the tag wiki edit privilege**. Don't waste reviewers' time on this.

Comment: On most sites, there isn't too much from them. Ok, I leave the Unix SE out of the story, however I think the whole task isn't enough big to implement a bot for it.

Comment: @peterh The bot already exists. It ran on questions and answers, it's just a matter of running it again, this time on tag wikis. I've had complaints about the edit queue being swamped with mechanical edits — this isn't about Unix.SE.

Comment: It seems, the problem isn't very important for the responsible people, as the view count and the lack of reactions show. Maybe it is because weekend. I post my current edits, and then I will stop until late monday. (Btw, I did already roughly 3/4 of the sites I wanted to clean up.) After that, we will see, what they say.

Comment: [Look](http://i.imgur.com/DVlWAAr.png)! :-)

Comment: Hi @peterh. Mind taking a look at this please: https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2335/96277?

Comment: Can be done, but will require some dev work. Why? The first step of our migration script used our elastic search index (it's what powers the /search route), to figure out which posts need to be modified / rebaked. It already contains all URLs extracted from each question / answer, and is very cheap to query across all sites, but it only contains questions and answers.

Comment: @peterh, potentially more accurate query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/716639/891871/tag-wikis-with-internal-http-links

Comment: @Cœur Hehh, thanks :-) I further improved it, may be nice, although it is now a little bit slow: https://data.stackexchange.com/android/query/716656/tag-wikis-with-internal-http-links . On the SO, it doesn't run because timeout, on other sites, yes.