# It is now impossible to make a suggested edit to a tag-info

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

When trying to suggest an edit to a tag-wiki (or to create a new tag-wiki), I get an error saying: "The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!"

[image: screenshot]

In theory, it could be possible that I was unlucky and the site where I was editing has actually [full edit queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84362) - but after I noticed this, I have tried the same on several sites, it seems unlikely that on all of them the queue is full.<sup>1</sup>

It seems that users who have sufficient reputation can edit the tag-wikis - I have seen relatively recent edits on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4651088/revisions) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75601921/revisions).

I have tried to check with SEDE<sup>2</sup> - but it seems that the problem started after the most recent update of the database. So from the public instance of SEDE we will only see whether there is a gap in suggested edits after the next update. (As far as I know, the devs can run queries on an instance of SEDE which is not public and which contains full data about deleted posts. I am not sure whether it has more recent data than the public instance.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If you want to try this for yourself, you can have a look at metas where [the tag support still has the default tag-info](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1602173/missing-tag-wikis-for-the-given-tag-only-metas-networkwide?tagname=support). The links to FAQ and search are both http rather than https - which is a rather minor edit, but if we're trying something just for testing purposes, this is a change that would at least make sense. (As opposed to some dummy test saying: "I am just testing a possible bug.")
Related: [Convert http links to https in tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300235) and [Change "http" to "https" in the tag-info imported for the default tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381423). (Perhaps I should explicitly say that I have encountered this problem when doing something else - but this place seemed like a reasonable place for testing purposes when I want to check whether the behavior on other sites will be the same.)

<sup>2</sup>Recent suggested edits:
[all metas](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1716784/recent-edit-suggestions-only-tag-info-including-tagname-all-metas),
[all sites except SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1716785/recent-edit-suggestions-only-tag-info-including-tagname-all-sites-except-so),
[Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1231352/recent-suggested-edits-on-tag-infos),
[Meta Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1231352/recent-suggested-edits-on-tag-infos). (I have checked SO separately, since the same query run over all sites times out.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry again folks.  For what it's worth, we did put in some additional monitoring for observability and feature flags in case we needed to easily rollback the latest round of changes.  And checked after re-applying the changes to see if we had a spike in the suggested edit queue being full (which is the same queue for questions and tag wikis alike).

Here's the timeline of us logging that the suggested edit queue was full (and a user attempted to submit an edit), which didn't suggest we had an unprecedent spike in errors, above and beyond normal variance.

[image: graph of suggested edit queue full events showing peak with first fix but not in second]

This only impacted tag wiki edits due to a tiny little `!` sign that was missed.  I'll be adding some extra testing in this area this week to make it easier for us to catch problems in this area before they reach prod.

This is fixed now in prod.  Thanks for the reports

Comment: Thanks for the fix! Can you also mark this related Movies & TV meta post as [[tag:status-completed]]? [Can't suggest an edit to a tag wiki: "The edit queue is full at the moment" error message is always shown even if the edit review queue is clear](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4911/1006)

Comment: @galacticninja, thanks, done!

Comment: I've tried to edit my first tag info this evening on StackOverflow and got this error. Is anybody else noticing a reoccurrence of this issue?