# Community Promotion Archive is not secured yet

Tags: feature-request, ssl

With all of Stack Exchange sites (except chat) [fully secured now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time), one site was forgotten: the [community promotion archive](http://stackpromos.com/promos).

Trying to change to [https manually](https://stackpromos.com/promos) leads to "Your connection is not private" warning.

Since this is official Stack Exchange site which is still in use, can it also please be given a secure connection?