# Is SEDE secure?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, ssl

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) aka SEDE is not mentioned in [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time).

It is not listed in any of the steps, which makes sense as it's not officially part of Stack Exchange, just an external site which is just hosted on SE domain.

Unlike SE sites, http://data.stackexchange.com is not redirecting to https://data.stackexchange.com, however since the SSL is for *.stackexchange.com data.stackexchange.com is also included and technically part of the SSL.

This means the [secure version of SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) works just fine, however it's not official. Yet.

So, my questions are:

- Is SEDE officially secured with the same SSL as the rest of Stack Exchange?
- Should we change links pointing to the non secure URL to the secure URL instead?

Comment: [Related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299181/295232) (so the same question could be asked for the SE API).

Comment: @Glorfindel good catch, well, Area 51 and StackApps are not ordinary Q&A site but integral part of SE.

Comment: But neither is SEDE ...

Comment: @Glorfindel I mean Area 51 and StackApps source code is part of SE  code, while SEDE code is not, which makes it... different.

Comment: Part of Stack Exchange's mission is to make the Internet better. Eradicating http link makes the Internet better. ;)

Comment: @Helmar not if the site is not officially SSL enabled for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's related to Taryn's work on [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316175/295232), but right now http://data.stackexchange.com is automatically redirecting to https://data.stackexchange.com. So it seems this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Yup, likely part of whatever fix she deployed there. :)

Comment: Sure, I'll take credit ;) Actually this appears to have been fixed a few weeks ago, by [Kyle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131182/kyle-brandt).