# Data explorer update seems to have failed

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I noticed the data Explorer update for September 30 at 3:00 UTC seems to have failed. Looking at the [Data Explorer main page](https://data.stackexchange.com/) it shows the last update was yesterday however the following query shows the last creation date in any table on Stack Overflow was from September 23:

[Stats about all SEDE TABLES including response time and last update date](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/873395/stats-about-all-sede-tables-including-response-time-and-last-update-date)

I tried the same query on about half a dozen other sites and they also showed the same date, so it seems to have failed for many if not all sites.

Comment: [The relevant person has been pinged already.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309917/whats-the-codegolf-temp-database-and-why-does-it-mess-up-my-query/309924?noredirect=1#comment1035897_309924)

Comment: @Glorfindel I wonder if this post is worth keeping? I didn't find that one because I only checked relatively recent questions but I guess Taryn might want to post a new answer if there was a different underlying reason.

Comment: It's useful (for the moment) if other people have the same question. Let's just wait for Taryn's reaction, I'm sure she'll notice this post as well.

Comment: It's perfectly fine, as it serves as a tracking point. Also, it's expected to file new bug reports if the same issue as a previous one comes up again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The weekly job did fail, and it was pretty much my fault. On Friday, I did a purge of old databases in production for SE sites that were no longer active, i.e. dead sites. I dropped the databases from the primary server and completely forgot that it would impact SEDE, if I didn't remove the counterpart on the SEDE server.

When the job kicked off over the weekend, it couldn't find the production version of several databases and it failed. As of this morning, I removed the databases from SEDE and manually started the refresh - it'll take about 6 hours to finish. I have also updated the docs to cover all the steps that need to be completed when dropping old sites (we don't do it very often, so it was easily missed).

In the meantime, please be mesmerized by these sad pug eye as an apology.

[image]