# Why doesn't Area 51 use HTTPS by default?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, ssl

On the page https://stackexchange.com/sites, there is a link to Area 51.

This link doesn't use HTTPS and Area 51 doesn't redirect to the HTTPS page.

> [image]
>
> [image: Area 51 use HTTP]

Comment: Not only [Area 51, few others too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299181/312043)

Comment: strange thing is the main post there (I'd say question but in the broadest sense of the term) says A51 is on HTTPS.

Comment: and https://area51.stackexchange.com works perfectly so... the redirect might simply not have been set.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yeah, it just needs the redirect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does now :)

It doesn't get as much love as it should, but we're cleaning up some issues here and I've just deployed `https://` redirects for Area 51.