# Community user profile has a non-HTTPS link in the "About" section

Tags: bug, status-deferred, profile-page, community-user, ssl

I was recently [reading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/399694) about [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), when I noticed this ironic, very minor, problem in its profile: the link to [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/399694) in the profile's "About" section is not HTTPS.

[image]

However, [Stack Exchange moved to HTTPS almost two years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/399694) and Community adds HTTPS to links, so this profile should have HTTPS.

---

This was tested by viewing the source of Community's profiles on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) and [Science Fiction and Fantasy Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). It's different from [The website link field is inconsistent between Community's profiles across sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374208/295232) - that's about the 'meta.stackexchange.com' link in the header.

Comment: @JNat this is strictly speaking not a duplicate, right? This is about a link in the profile description, and the linked duplicate is about the website field?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist: ...I just realized that as well (I was only looking at the website field, in my comments on the answer here). Good point. That said,  in either regard, I think fixing this would require manually editing the profiles – or running a script to fix them, per the reply to the linked question.

Comment: I made a note so both issues are fixed at once, @TheAmplitwist

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it has not been solved yet on the majority of communities.

To ease the work of the Community Managers, I made a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1554809/user-profiles-with-http-links?AccountID=-1) to check - right now, it returns 347 Community user profiles (including Meta sites) with HTTP links, but please note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. No doubt it will be better next week ...

Comment: Or in 6-8 sundays from now.

Comment: @Luuklag in which century?

Comment: Glorfindel, can you please update the link in [MSE Community bot profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)?

Comment: @RandomPerson I could, but as [mentioned here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380884/295232), it doesn't make that much of a difference. It's better if staff does it network-wide.

Answer (score -1):

I tested the profile out across a few different Meta and this was fixed a while back. I've updated to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: I don't think this has been fixed, e.g. [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/), [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/), [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/-1/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/users/-1/) and probably others. The only one I visited that was fine is [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

Comment: @RafaelTavares It appears to be fixed on those sites you mention when I look but I'll keep an eye out and ears open. If others report this still appears broken I'll move back to status-review so we can investigate.

Comment: @Rosie: When I checked just now, the MSE link was using https:// but the others that Rafael linked were still using http:// – I've gone ahead and fixed those now. (I wouldn't be surprised if there are others across the network that need fixing as well.)

Comment: @V2Blast moved back to status-review so we can check them all and confirm it's correct on every site.

Comment: MSE is really not `https` for me, I don't know if I should blame cache. I'm verifying it by [dragging the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lWnh.png) (on Opera GX it shows me the `href` value) and [inspecting the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1RTI.png) (or just right click and copy the link). As expected, clicking on the links redirects me to the `https` URL.

Comment: It's not fixed even here on MSE, so not sure where you tested. Another option is that something rolled back the fix.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Should this answer be deleted?

Comment: @RandomPerson no, it does "attempt to answer the question" so valid, just incorrect.