# The website link field is inconsistent between Community's profiles across sites

Tags: bug, status-deferred, profile-page, hyperlinks, community-user

On [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), the website link field for Community's profile is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/`. On [RPG SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) it's `http://meta.stackexchange.com/`. On [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) it's missing altogether.

While this is obviously very minor, so many things are standardized between Community's profiles that it's odd this isn't.

Comment: Moderators can edit the profile description (and hat) of Community, if I recall, so they can work around this.

Comment: Yeah, but its per site, and we'd need 100+ mods involved to check and standardise. And Community dosen't have a save for all sites button.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's a pain.  Don't you think it should have one?

Comment: Actually, some powers might be too much for mortal sapients to handle. IMAGINE THE POTENTIAL CHAOS.

Comment: @Ollie Not a good idea, because Community has a different profile on localized sites. FWIW, I just edited my site's Community to be HTTPS.

Comment: @Laurel Good point.  Would it be possible to push changes to the network excluding those sites then?

Comment: Isn't it better to push to all 170+ sites and then let the <10 localized sites deal with updating, rather than individually updating 170+ sites? Overall pushing to all sites looks to be 1/17th as much work.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah, some profiles, for reasons I haven't fully identified, don't have a "Save and copy to all public communities" button. However, you can just add the button and it works. In the browser console, you can run: `$('.edit-profile #form-submit button').after(' <button class="s-btn s-btn__primary js-save-button" data-push="true" data-prompt="true" type="button" tabindex="32"> Save and copy changes to all public communities </button>');`

Comment: Honestly with community, I'm not taking the risk. Its less work to escalate it to TPTB then monkeypatching it, breaking it and THEN escalating it.

Comment: Given the Community user doesn't have an underlying network account like regular users do, I can't just fix this with a "save to all communities" edit to the profile. As such, the easiest way to fix this that doesn't require me going through each individual profile manually is for a dev to run a script to fix it — added this to the backlog, to be addressed as a part of bug duty.

Comment: Related: [Community user profile has a non-HTTPS link in the "About" section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327242/335251)

Answer (score 2):

Just like [Community user profile has a non-HTTPS link in the "About" section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327242/295232), I made a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1622464/user-profiles-with-deviating-website-links?AccountID=-1&WebsiteURLNotEqualTo=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com) to check - right now, it returns 231 Community user profiles (including Meta sites) where it links to http://meta.stackexchange.com instead of using HTTPS. It also finds instances without website links, or where it's linking to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/` (note the trailing slash). In case staff is actively working on this issue when you view this answer (written August 2022): please note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. The information may be stale.

FWIW, ♦ moderators can update this field for the Community user on their own site (just like they can for *all* users except staff members) but for the Community user, the button 'Save and copy changes to all public communities' is missing, so it's better if staff fixes this for all sites at once.

Comment: Does your query account for Community profiles which lack any website link, as in Literature SE?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Even worse, I managed to not include the actual link to the query, and since [login is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380834/295232), I can't even find it under the list of queries I've created/edited ... Thanks a lot for the ping, I'll see what I can do.