# Can't login to SEDE - "StackApps authentication failed"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, data-explorer, login

When I try to [login to the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login) using Stack Overflow, it fails with the following error message:

> StackApps authentication failed

I've tried several browsers, and even in incognito mode it's not working so it can't be a cookie problem. Also when I try to login with a sockpuppet account, which hasn't logged in before, it asks for permission (which is expected) but then fails with the same error message.

[image]

Comment: And the Stack API itself is up, right?

Comment: I can run sample requests from the API documentation page, yes.

Comment: Log in using Google works for me, so it doesn't seem to be an issue in the shared authentication flow.

Comment: "certificate has expired" is an error I get in an auth flow. But when I visit the host directly in the browser the cert is fine and valid. I have an app that posts to `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token` and that returns me a certificate has expired.

Comment: I was trying to get my hands on the actual expired certificate but I managed to IP block Glitch.com ....

Comment: I can login with google but I get a cross site script warning on FF which I haven't seen before.

Comment: @rene wow that deserves some special reward. ;-)

Comment: Now also reported on Meta Stack Overflow: ["StackApps authentication failed" on data.stackexchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419593/4751173)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this problem. I just tried and got the same result.

Comment: I was just now able to log in to SEDE using Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HenryEcker thanks, it works for me now as well.

Comment: Works for me, too

Comment: Yep. It has started working again.

Comment: As the comments indicate, this seems to no longer be an issue. In case it re-occurs, feel free to retag with [tag:status-review].

Comment: @bad_coder, if the bug was valid at some point in time it is left open (by us mere mortals) and could be red tagged (in this case by the OP), **only** if it's discovered early on that the user was at fault (often indicated by a few comments, which is [clearly not the case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419593/4751173) (and comments above)); so *we* don't close this, staff/a mod will (and have already done so) - though if you have an MSE dupe, that's another route.

Comment: @bad_coder, On MSO it's not the correct [default "SO Mode"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380834/cant-login-to-sede-stackapps-authentication-failed?noredirect=1#comment1274086_380834) though it seems to be rather [inconsistently applied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365633/3648282) by some people (comment here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386014/meta-question-closed-as-no-repro-after-bug-was-fixed#comment703089_386014 versus another comment there) except for the second reason (where there's seemingly agreement): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401383/3648282

Comment: If this is no longer a problem (I checked again), shouldn't it have a different tag?

Comment: Should mainly have an answer I guess.