# Is there a way to check the change of geographical distribution of user base on SE?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I found geographical distribution checkers on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/queries?q=Geographic), but is there a way to see how the population changes with time?

I want to see, for instance, from what country most people are joining vs from what country most people are leaving SE.

Comment: How do you define "leaving" (in this context)?

Comment: How did you manage to log into SEDE? I got *"[StackApps authentication failed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380834/)"* when I tried right now. For example, what authentication provider do you use?

Comment: This would be SO specifically, but... there is [a question on the yearly SO survey](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#section-key-territories-geography) asking "Where do you live?". You could compare the results from this year to previous years to get an idea of this. Would that work for you...?

Comment: Just a population graph over time @This_is_NOT_a_forum

Comment: I want specifically for MSE , chemistry stack @cocomac

Comment: We don't have "deleted" users in SEDE, so you have to be more precise what "leaving" means. For Users we do have creationdate and LastAccessDate.

Comment: Basically I want a way to see the Geographical number of users w.r.t time @rene

Comment: @rene guess by "leaving" OP means "becoming inactive", which can be measured to some extent in SEDE.

Comment: Yes more or less @ShadowTheKidWizard