# URL link issue in data explorer tutorial page

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, ssl

There is an issue with a URL, in one of the Data Explorer tutorial pages.

In the [**Tutorial -> Next Steps**](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/next-steps) page, I can see the following description

> You can find some interesting queries in [this list on one of our sites](https://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2014/28). For *tons* of interesting queries and starting points for your own work, see ...

In the description, the link is pointing to

```
https://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2014/28
```

but actually, it should be

```
https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2014/28
```

As per the [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/312043) post, the meta URL change was done:

> **Update 2017-03-16**
>
> We've redirected all child meta traffic from `meta.*.stackexchange.com` to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`, and are now forcing HTTPS.

But the change was not applied on this tutorial page. Can this be corrected?

In Google Chrome browser, after clicking on the URL, I'm receiving the following error page:

> [image: Error page]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've created  a [pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/92) to fix that specific link.

Allow for 6 to 8 weeks before Nick does a pull/merge and re-deploy.