# Meta.*.stackexchange.com sitewise certificate issue

Tags: bug, ssl, dns

There is a bug where I see a privacy error on all meta.foo.stackexchange.com sites. For example, if I try to enter meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com into my browser, I get this warning: [image]

Can someone check this out?

Comment: Are you going to http:// or https:// ?

Comment: https://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm going to https://

Comment: It works with https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh. Yeah. I can never remember which is the "correct" version. We switched it at some point. My understanding is that we don't support the meta.[sitename].stackexchange.com any more since we swapped the order.

Comment: Could probably make this a duplicate of the announcement https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time

Comment: I get that.. I would think that it would be a good idea to still have it be in the certificate so the warning doesn't pop up every time someone tries to access it.

Comment: This is by design (I think).  All meta URL's are now <site>.meta.stackexchange.com; any meta.<site>.stackexchange.com should redirect.

Comment: I understand... but my possibly faulty memory is that we actually switched the order *because* getting the certificates would be really difficult. Doing it anyway defeats the purpose of swapping the url around.

Comment: Oh, ok. I see the response and that is coorect