# Harmonize display names for automatic URL rewrites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, community-user, ssl

A couple of years ago, [Stack Exchange switched to HTTPS-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/295232) and all internal links were rewritten by (non-bumping) edits by the Community user, like [this one here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/296265/revisions).

[image]

I just noticed that on Stack Overflow (and perhaps on some other sites as well), all those edits are attributed to a deleted (or rather non-existing) user "URL Rewriter Bot" instead ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1417190/revisions)):

[image]

On the question page itself, the edit *is* attributed to the Community user:

[image]

For consistency's sake, should/could this be fixed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was done intentionally so they wouldn't all be connected to the Community user profile and end up completely breaking the profile. Throwing the Community user Id into the last editor field, though, isn't a big deal because it's denormalized data. // Yes, this was changed after the script ran to fix an issue: [Accessing Community's profile "all actions" tab timeout](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377547/accessing-communitys-profile-all-actions-tab-timeout) (MSO)

Comment: Given the reasoning mentioned in @animuson's comment, I think it's safe to mark this one as [status-declined].

Comment: @V2Blast What can be done, on the other hand, is to change the denormalized field of the last editor so it matches the same user as the one in the actual last revision. That would also "harmonize" it.

Comment: @Sonic That would be a much more significant amount of effort that I doubt our dev team would be interested in doing for such a minor issue.

Comment: Ah, so this is a classic case of Stack Overflow being a league of its own. It could be an option to use "URL Rewriter Bot" on all sites, but I guess it wouldn't be 100% consistent then either. Thanks for the explanation @animuson!