# Should http links within the SE network be automatically converted to https?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks, ssl, linked-questions

I have noticed that occasionally some people still link to some other posts using `http` rather than `https`.
Two random examples I have seen recently: [Dependent multiple choice vs. dependent choice](https://mathoverflow.net/q/436420) - which was [edited in the meantime](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/436420/revisions) -  and [A determinant involving the cotangent function](https://mathoverflow.net/q/403098). (I noticed this mainly because I saw a question with the empty list of linked questions despite linking to another post on the same site - and I was in the process of writing a bug report, when I noticed that this was caused by the link being http.)

Would it be better if a link to a post on Stack Exchange site would be automatically turned to https-link, even if the user enters it as http? (When creating a new post - and perhaps even when editing an already existing one.)

If nothing else, this would cause the question to appear among linked questions. But in general, many links have been converted from http to https back in 2017: [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058). So it would be consistent to use https as a preferred option in the new posts, too.

Comment: I'd support this but only if it doesn't cause any errors. Note that https://meta.site.stackexchange.com gives an error while the http version does not.

Answer (score 7):

It seems odd to have done a bulk migration but then not applied it to anything new.

Either a regular re-run or doing it automatically appears to be a good idea.