# Make all links in 'Stack Gives Back 2022!' and 'Stack Gives Back 2023!' HTTPS

Tags: feature-request, blog, ssl

Two links in [Stack Gives Back 2022!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/01/12/stack-gives-back-2022/) are HTTP, while their HTTPS equivalents work fine:

- [Doctors Without Borders (Médecins Sans Frontières)](http://doctorswithoutborders.org/)
- [UNICEF](http://www.unicef.org/)

In the spirit of [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/295232), can these links please be updated?

This is also the case in [Stack Gives Back 2023!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/01/22/stack-gives-back-2023/) where those exact same links are there as well.

Comment: It's just a copy&paste from [last year](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/01/13/stack-gives-back-2021/), where nobody noticed the missing SSL, and most likely that's how it was in all the previous 12 posts as well, and would be in the next 50 unless you spotted it. (Well, might still be, sometimes they don't notice requests here on MSE)

Comment: I'm not very shocked that they ignored this and copied and pasted again with the wrong URL's. lol (sad laugh.)

Comment: Perhaps this is better as an "answer" on [the announcement "question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396278/stack-gives-back-2023-is-now-complete).