# Stack Gives Back 2023 is now complete!

Tags: discussion, blog, donation

Stack Gives Back is an annual tradition where the company donates $100 to a charity on behalf of each moderator on the Stack Exchange network. We are thrilled to announce that **we donated $53,600 USD to six different organizations** this year! Read more about it [on the blog here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/01/22/stack-gives-back-2023/).

Thank you to all the wonderful moderators, curators, and community members who contributed to the Stack Exchange network in 2023!